# Copying AJAX JSON object into existing Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have several Javascript prototypes. Initially, instances will have only ID's filled in, with some generic place holder information for other data. I then send a message to the server with the ID and the object type (using jQuery's AJAX function) and the server returns a JSON object with all the missing information (but no ID). The variables in the returned object have the exact same name as those in the existing object.

What's the easiest way to transfer this into the existing empty object? I've come up with a few alternatives

- set the object equal to the returned object, then copy in the id (loses prototype functions?)
- create a function for each object that takes an object with identical structure and copies the data
- loop through the key-value pairs of the JSON object to and copy them to existing object

If I use the third option, is this the correct way to do that? :

```
for (var key in json) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        object[key] = json[key];
    }
}
```

assuming `json` is the returned object and `object` is the existing object.

Comment: If `json` is plain JSON then I don't think you even need the `hasOwnProperty` check. Unless someone has been funking with `Object.prototype`.

Comment: The question is, what do you want to do with your JSON-Object. If you want to evaluate to an object, JSON.parse() does the trick for you. If you want to merge it to an existing object, jQuery.extend() would be a better suggestion.

Comment: @PaulGrime I'm doing that as a precaution in case there's an extra key in the `json` object that I don't want in the existing `object`. If you'll notice, I'm looping through keys in `json` but checking against `object`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this using [**extend()**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/):

```
var newObject = jQuery.extend({}, oldObject);
```

Comment: Sounds perfect! I wasn't aware of this functionality at all. And because it merges all properties, any inheritance I have done will still stick, correct?

Answer (score 18):

Alternative without jQuery is to use the javascript Object.assign method.

`Object.assign(targetObject, json);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery.extend: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

```
$.extend(object1,object2);
```

If your JSON is a string then create an object from that first:

```
var object1=$.parseJSON(myJsonString);
```

Comment: There is no need for a Methodcall parseJSON(), hence nowadays everybody could use JSON.parse(). jQuery does nothing else:     if (window.JSON && window.JSON.parse) {
                return window.JSON.parse(data);
            }

Comment: but if window.JSON.parse is false it'll do a bit more.

Comment: but window.JSON.parse will not fail today