# angular2 map data as specific object type

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I created a very simple app based on the Angular2 tutorial.

To start, I have a very simple "Book" model:

```
 /**
 * book model
 */
export class Book {
    public data;

    /**
     * constructor
     * @param id
     * @param title
     * @param pages
     */
    constructor(
        public id,
        public title:string,
        public pages:Array
    ){
        alert('it works'); // just a check
    }
}
```

In my service, I get a book like this:

```
return this._http.get('getBook/1')
        .map(function(res){
            return <Book> res.json();
        })
```

My expectation was that this would get the resulting JSON data and "map" it to a Book object.

However, it just returns an object with type "Object".

I could create a new Book object myself and pass the parameters in the constructor, like this:

```
return new Book(res.id, res.title, res.pages);
```

Is this the best way to do this? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, casting an object to a type in TypeScript doesn't create an instance of this type. It's just a facility of TypeScript for type checking.

If you want actually an instance of `Book` you need to use something like that:

```
return this._http.get('getBook/1')
    .map(function(res){
        var data = res.json();
        return new Book(data.id, data.title, data.pages);
    })
```

**To answer your question**. In fact if you only have fields into your type (with an interface for example), casting is enough. Moreover if you have methods you want to use later, it's necessary to implicitly create an instance of the `Book` type (see above) instead of casting. Otherwise you won't be able to use them (they will be undefined on your object)...

See this question for more details:

- [How do I cast a JSON object to a typescript class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875636/how-do-i-cast-a-json-object-to-a-typescript-class)

Comment: Couldn't this approach get out of hand if the object you're instantiating has several other custom objects? How do you handle a more deeply nested object in this case?

Answer (score 5):

I think you should declare an interface `Book` instead of class `book`:

```
export interface Book {
    public id;
    public title:string;
    public pages:Array;
}
```

In your service:

```
//get one record
return this._http.get('getBook/1')
        .map(function(res){
            return <Book> res.json();
        });

//get multi record
return this._http.get('getBooks')
        .map(function(res){
            return <Book> res.json();
        });
```

Answer (score 5):

Good practice is to consume data from GET response using

```
Observable<Model>
```

(regarding to Angular documentation https://angular.io/guide/http)
And then:

// imports

```
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
```

// in constructor parameter list

```
private http: HttpClient
```

// service method

```
getBook(): Observable<Book> {return this.http.get<Book>({url}, {options});}
```

Answer (score 2):

From https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-a-typed-response

> To specify the response object type, first define an interface with
> the required properties. Use an interface rather than a class, because
> the response is a plain object that cannot be automatically converted
> to an instance of a class.

Always receive response using interface because only thing that's happening is  mapping fields, and you cannot use class if you have instance function which will throw error when you use that object.

```
product.getPrice is not a function
```

**Example**

```js
interface ProductInterface {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  price: number;
}

class Product implements ProductInterface {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  price: number;
  
  constructor(productData: ProductInterface) {
    this.id = product.id;
    this.name = product.name;
    this.price = product.price;
  }
  
  public getPrice(): string {
    return this.price + " INR";
  }
}
```

```js
class ProducService {
  ...
  ...


  getProduct(): Observable<Product> {
    return this.http.get<Product>('assets/product.json').pipe(map(data => new Product(data))); 
  }

  getProductWithoutMappingToClass(): Observable<Product> {
    return this.http.get<Product>('assets/product.json');
  } // Throw runtimerror ctx_r1.product.getPrice is not a function
}
```

Comment: this is the correct answer, for people using the latest versions of angular (12+) - these versions don't required anymore the .map<ObjType>(..), get() accepts it already