# How do you call a web service that returns single JSON object in Angular 2?

Tags: json, web-services, typescript, angular

Trying to call a webservice from Angular 2 that returns a single Json object:

```
{
   "fullDisplayName": "test",
   "result": "SUCCESS"
}
```

Below are the code snippets for my route:

**Service**

```
getJsonObject () {
    return this.http.get(this.url)
                    .map(res => <jsonObject> res.json())
                    .do(jsonObject=> console.log(jsonObject))
                    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

**Component**

```
getJsonObject() {
   console.log('BEFORE')
   this.service.getJsonObject()
      .subscribe(
          jsonObject=> this.jsonObject = jsonObject,
          error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
          console.log(this.jsonObject)
          console.log("AFTER")
 }
```

All that I get is a undefined object but I can see the JSON in the console log in chrome. The funny thing is I place a log in the component before and after the call, both those logs are displayed before the JSON found is displayed in log, making it look like it's somehow trying to map the object before the web service returns the data.

**Console Log**

```
 Angular 2 is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
 BEFORE
 undefined
 AFTER
 Object {fullDisplayName: "test", result: "SUCCESS"}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is `jsonObject` or how does it look like? Looks like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875636/how-do-i-cast-a-json-object-to-a-typescript-class

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer
The jsonObject looks like this.
`export class JsonObject{
  constructor(
    public fullDisplayName:string,
    public result:string) { }
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     console.log(this.jsonObject)
     console.log("AFTER")
```

is executed before the request to `this.url` is even sent to the server. `Observable` is async and execution is enqueued into the event queue and when the response arrives the callback you passed to `subscribe(...)` is executed.

This is what you actually need to do:

```
getJsonObject() {
   console.log('BEFORE')
   this.service.getJsonObject()
      .subscribe(
          jsonObject=> {
              this.jsonObject = jsonObject,
              console.log(this.jsonObject)
              console.log("AFTER")
          },
          error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
 }
```

Comment: Ah I see, that makes sense. However it is still not showing in my HTML.

{{ jsonObject.result }} 

This outputs no data even though the log is showing the object as being populated.

Comment: Is it printing to the console? Do you get an error in the console? I guess you need `{{jsonObject?.result }}` See also the link in my comment below your question.

Comment: That was it. It just needed the question mark! I have created used web services before but they have always returned arrays which have not needed the ? to be referenced.

Thanks you for your help.