# Typing JSON objects coming from the backend as proper typescript classes with methods

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I am trying to map the json returned from the backend to proper typescript classes on the angular side.

Here is my backend code:

```
findMessagesWithOtherUserAccount(otherId:Number):Observable<Message[]> {
    return this.http.get('/api/message/find-messages-with-other-useraccount/' + otherId)
        .map(this.extractMessages);
}

private extractMessages(res:Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body || {};
}
```

Notice the `Observable` of `Message`. Here `Message` is the type I need because I have added business logic to the class as follows:

```
import {UserAccount} from "../useraccount/useraccount.model";

export class Message {

    constructor(id:number,
                sender:UserAccount,
                recipient:UserAccount,
                sendDate:Date,
                messageRead:boolean,
                text:string) {
        this.id = id;
        this.sender = sender;
        this.recipient = recipient;
        this.sendDate = sendDate;
        this.messageRead = messageRead;
        this.text = text;
    }

    id:number;
    sender:UserAccount;
    recipient:UserAccount;
    sendDate:Date;
    messageRead:boolean;
    text:string;

    getCounterparty(user:UserAccount):UserAccount {
        if (!this.sender) return null;
        return (user.id !== this.sender.id) ? this.sender : this.recipient;
    }

    isSender(user:UserAccount):boolean {
        return user.id === this.sender.id;
    }

    isRecipient(user:UserAccount):boolean {
        return user.id === this.recipient.id;
    }

    isNew(user:UserAccount):boolean {
        return !this.messageRead && this.isRecipient(user);
    }
}
```

I try to refer to the `isRecipient` method from a component:

```
   getSenderFirstName(message:Message):string {
        if (message.isRecipient(this.currentUserAccount)) {
            return this.otherUserAccount.firstName;
        }
        return 'Moi';//FIXME: i18n/translate
    }
```

However, I get this error:

```
browser_adapter.js:81 TypeError: message.isRecipient is not a function
    at MessageConversationComponent.getSenderFirstName (message-conversation.component.js:50)
```

Indicating that message is not typed (other than a plain js object)...

Here is the full component:

```
export class MessageConversationComponent implements OnInit {

    messagesWithOtherUserAccount:Message[];
    currentUserAccount:UserAccount;
    otherUserAccount:UserAccount;

    constructor(private messageService:MessageService,
                private userAccountService:UserAccountService,
                private routeSegment:RouteSegment) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.messageService.findMessagesWithOtherUserAccount(2)
            .subscribe(param=>this.messagesWithOtherUserAccount = param);
        this.userAccountService.retrieveOtherUserAccount(2)
            .subscribe(param=> this.otherUserAccount = param); 
   this.userAccountService.currentUserAccount$.subscribe(param=>this.currentUserAccount = param);
    }

    getSenderFirstName(message:Message):string {
        if (message.isRecipient(this.currentUserAccount)) {
            return this.otherUserAccount.firstName;
        }
        return 'Moi';//FIXME: i18n/translate
    }
}
```

and the template:

```
            <div *ngFor="let message of messagesWithOtherUserAccount" class="media col-xs-12">
                <div class="media-body Lui" ng-class="getMessageClasses(message)">
                    <div class="media-heading">
                        {{getSenderFirstName(message)}} <small><span am-time-ago="message.sendDate"></span></small>
                    </div>
                    <p class="message-text">{{message.text}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Typescript doesn't provide any extra methods to convert a plain object to a class instance. You should define a interface for `Message` which only contains plain properties.

Comment: Marking the return type of your function to be of a TypeScript type won't make the actual object be an instance of that type. The object you receive doesn't have the prototypical functions for the class Message you defined

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I cast a JSON object to a typescript class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875636/how-do-i-cast-a-json-object-to-a-typescript-class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just cast JSON to a class instance. If you actually need a class with methods you need to create it with `new SomeClass()` like:

```
private extractMessages(res:Response) {
    let body = res.json();

    if(body) {
      return new Message(
        body.id,
        new UserAccount(body.sender),
        new UserAccount(body.recipient),
        new Date(body.sendDate),
        body.messageRead,
        body.text);
    } else {
      return new Message(
    }
}
```

If you only want typed access to properties you can use an interface instead of a class and cast to this interface instead to get autocompletion and static type checking.