# Parse a JSON response Angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular

Does anyone know how I can parse a JSON response into a structure like this?

```
   [
  {
    "iD": 2,
    "OrderList": [
      {
        "bidPrice": 0,
        "iD": 0,
        "name": "Name",
        "price": 10,
        "resteurant": "Restaurant"
      },
      {
        "bidPrice": 0,
        "iD": 0,
        "name": "Something",
        "price": 20,
        "resteurant": "La Place"
      }
],
    "owner": "Tom"
  }
]
```

I used json2ts to create these two structures:

```
  import {OrderList} from "./OrderList.ts";
import {Injectable} from  "@angular/core";

@Injectable()

export interface OrderBasket {
    iD: number;
    OrderList: OrderList[];
    owner: string;
}
```

and

```
import {Injectable} from  "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export interface OrderList {
    bidPrice: number;
    iD: number;
    name: string;
    price: number;
    resteurant: string;
}
```

I make a call to the server and subscribe, but i cannot get this structure.
Can anyone help ?

Comment: How are you getting your hands on that  JSON response? I mean, how do you receive/get that data? This is important for us to give you options.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that you could try the following:

```
this.http.get('http://...')
  .map(res => <OrderBasket[]>res.json())
  .subscribe(data => {
    // data corresponds to a list of OrderBasket
  });
```

You need to be aware of implications of casting with TypeScript:

- [How do I cast a JSON object to a typescript class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875636/how-do-i-cast-a-json-object-to-a-typescript-class)

Otherwise, I don't understand why you use the `Injectable` decorator on your interfaces.