# Whats the best way to cast JSON to generic Object[] in angular 2 typescript?

Tags: angularjs, json, angular, angular2-http

Not sure if this works as intended, but I want to convert a blob of json into an array of generic objects (the objects are malleable and can change depending on my URL). Should I use JSON.parse(res.json().data) instead? Thanks.

```
 return this.http.get(URL)
                       .toPromise()
                       .then(response => response.json().data as Object[]) 
                       .catch(this.handleError);
          }
```

Comment: Does this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875636/how-do-i-cast-a-json-object-to-a-typescript-class

Comment: No, I dont know what properties the object will have so a typescript class wouldn't suit my needs. I'd rather convert it to a generic javascript object

Comment: Well you can do `as any[]` to do an unsafe cast, but if you're using this function in many places it would be worth putting in a real type for that response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your solution is that the `Object` type doesn't have any members (other than the usual) so any attempt to access specific properties from your JSON like `id` etc will create an error.

The correct way is `as any[]`:

```
  return this.http.get(URL)
                        .toPromise()
                        .then(response => response.json().data as any[]) 
                        .catch(this.handleError);
           }
```

This will let you access everything that was in the JSON response (as well as everything that wasn't in the JSON response. You'll get an error at runtime).

It would be better to cast the result to a specific type, see [How do I cast a JSON object to a typescript class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875636/how-do-i-cast-a-json-object-to-a-typescript-class)

Comment: The way I have my app set up, I pass two variables to determine which object to get from backend, and from there populate a google chart. I figured a generic object would be easiest for quickly adding charts and plugging in info, is there a big advantage to using a typescript class that would offset having to create a bunch of different http calls, rather than one unified call?

Comment: Well, you'd get type safety ;) and auto completion in your editor. It's more important for larger projects.

Comment: Your caller knows what the type should be right? You can make this method generic, say `getFromServer<T>(URL_params)` and then do the cast `as T[]`. Then, the return value of this function will be a `Promise<T[]>`.