# Typescript object from JSON

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I'm using TypeScript to build an app and I'm making API calls to retrieve objects. For instance, I have a TypeScript `User` Object like this:

```
export class User {
    id : number;
    name : string;
    email : string;
}
```

And my API returns

```
{
    "id" : 3,
    "name" : "Jonn",
    "email" : "john@example.com"
}
```

I want to convert that JSON to a `User`. I've read in another posts I can do this:

```
let user : User = <User> myJson;
```

This seemly works. I can access properties of the user like `user.name`but my problem is that, if the `User` class implements some method, the properties are not available. For example, if inside the `User` class I have this:

```
getUppercaseName() : string {
    return this.name.toUppercase();
}
```

This happens:
`user.name` returns `John` but `user.getUppercaseName()` returns `undefined`

What's going on? How to solve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing it treating classes as interfaces, as this will work exactly the same:

```
export interface User {
    id : number;
    name : string;
    email : string;
}
```

The reason that the compiler doesn't complain about you using classes this way [is because](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#introduction):

> One of TypeScript’s core principles is that type-checking focuses on
>   the shape that values have. This is sometimes called “duck typing” or
>   “structural subtyping”

([read more about duck typing](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Duck_typing))

Or with an example:

```
class User {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    email: string;

    constructor(id: number, name: string, email: string) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
    }
}

function logUser(user: User) {
    console.log(`user id: ${ user.id }, name: ${ user.name }, email: ${ user.email }`);
}

logUser({
    id: 1,
    name: "user 1",
    email: "mailaddress"
});

logUser(new User(2, "user 2", "anotheraddress"));
```

In the two calls to `logUser` I pass objects that satisfy the interface of the `User` class.

If you want to have an instance of that class instead of an object that satisfies it then you should do something like:

```
new User(myJson.id, myJson.name, myJson.email);
```

And have a constructor like in my example, or:

```
interface IUser {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    email: string;
}

class User implements IUser {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    email: string;

    constructor(data: IUser) {
        this.id = data.id;
        this.name = data.name;
        this.email = data.email;
    }
}

...
new User(myJson);
```

Comment: I think the question is how to convert json data to a particular class instance.
Something like that should work (assuming there's a user's constructor), but gives me error when I use the result in ngIf

        return this._http.get(this.urll)
            .map((res: Response) => res.json())
            .map(obj:any => {return new User(obj.number, obj.name, obj.email);})

Comment: @rook There's no need for using `map` twice.. this should work: `this._http.get(this.urll).map((res: Response) => { let json = res.json(); return new User(json.id, json.name, json.email); })`. What error do you get?

Comment: Yes, it's shorter but the error is the same: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: @rook I suggest that you post a new question with your error along with your code. It's hard to understand code/problems in the comments, plus with a new question you'll have more people to help except for me. Also, it's not related to this question or my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Nitzan pretty much explained the theory behind this, so I'll just provide an alternative approach:

```
interface UserInfo {
   id: number;
   name: string;
   email: string;
}

class User {
   userInfo: UserInfo;
   constructor(userInfo: UserInfo) {
       this.userInfo = userInfo;
   }
   getUpperCaseName(): string {
       return this.userInfo.name.toLocaleUpperCase();
   }
}

const json = {
   id: 3,
   name: "Jonn",
   email: "john@example.com"
}

let user: User = new User(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem when your User has 50 or more properties...

Add a constructor in your User object so that it extends your json object.

```
export class User {
    constructor( jsonUser: any )
    {
      $.extend(this, jsonUser);
    }
    id : number;
    name : string;
    email : string;
    getUpperCaseName() {...}
}
```

In your ajax callback, create the User object from your json Object:

```
let receivedUser = new User( jsonUser );
let userName = receivedUser.getUpperCaseName();
```

I detailed the solution in that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875636/how-do-i-cast-a-json-object-to-a-typescript-class/41046474#41046474).