# angular2 & typescript & reactiveX : how to cast http get result

Tags: angular, typescript, casting, frontend, reactivex

Lets suppose we have a rest api at this url `/api/stuffs/` where we can get a list of `Stuff`.

here is the code to http get the list of `Stuff`:

```
getStuffs(): Observable<Stuff[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.url)
        .map(this.extractStuffs)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}

private extractStuffs(res: Response) {

    let stuffs = res.json() as Stuff[];

    return stuffs || new Array<Stuff>();
}
```

everything works fine with this code, except the fact that the `stuffs` array in the `extractStuffs` function is not an array of `Stuff` but and array of `Object` instead, even if the signature of the function is `Observable<Stuff[]>` and the result from the api is casted to `Stuff[]`. What's weird is that typescript compiler is not throwing any error (even if result type is different from signature), witch is totally normal if we take a look at the generated JS file :

```
StuffService.prototype.extractStuffs = function (res) {
    var stuffs = res.json();
    return stuffs || new Array();
};
```

So obviously casting the result into `Stuff[]` is not even considered by the compiler.

Is there any way to cast it properly without doing it manually ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Every time I am in a similar situation I do casting through a loop (which I guess you define manually).

This is an example with Customers instead of Stuffs

```
getCustomers(code: string) {
        let url = environment.baseServicesUrl + 'customer';
        let jsonParam = {code: code};
        return this.http.post(url, jsonParam, this.getOptions())
                    .map(this.extractData)
                    .map((customerJsons) => {
                        let customers = new Array<Customer>();
                        customerJsons.forEach((customerJson) => {
                            customers.push(<Customer>customerJson);
                        })
                        return customers
                    })
                    .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

The casting type Customer is an interface.

Here is the code of **Customer.interface.ts**

```
import {Relationship} from './relationship.interface';

export interface Customer {
    customerId: string;
    name: string;
    lastName: string;
    code: string;
    relationships: Array<Relationship>;
}
```

Here is the code for **Relationship.interface.ts**

```
export interface Relationship {
    id: string;
    type: string;
}
```

Comment: omitted to say that single object casting is not working either, the `<Stuff>stuffJson` still returns an `Object` instead of `Stuff`. here is the generated js => `jsonStuffs.forEach(function (jsonStuff) { return stuffs.push(jsonStuff); });` could something be missing in my compiler ???

Comment: Stuff needs to be an interface (not a class) for casting to work, I guess. Is this the case with you?

Comment: its a class indeed. ill retry with an interface.

Comment: the interface didnt change much

Comment: I have edited my answer with the complete code, including the interface. I hope this helps

Comment: Maybe it is worth also adding that interfaces in Typescript are not compiled into runtime code. They are usefull to enforce typing at development time. See (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875636/how-do-i-cast-a-json-object-to-a-typescript-class)

Comment: yeah, thats the problem. no casting in typescript at runtime :(