# How to cast all nodes of a nested JSON tree to instances of a class in angular 2 Typescript?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I have a class named Leaf, and I'd like to make all nodes of a json response instances of Leaf.
The json response looks like this:

**JSON Response**

```
{
    "name":"animal",
    "state":false,
    "children":[
        {
            "name":"cats",
            "state":false,
            "children":[
                {
                    "name":"tiger",
                    "state":false,
                },
                {
                    "name":"puma",
                    "state":false,
                    "children":[
                        {
                            "name":"babyPuma",
                            "state":true
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name":"dogs",
            "state":false,
            "children":[
                {
                    "name":"pitbull",
                    "state":true
                },
                {
                    "name":"german",
                    "state":false,
                    "children":[
                        {
                            "name":"shepherd",
                            "state":true
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am getting the response using observable and have learned to cast the first node:

**http.service.ts snippet**

```
getTreeData(): Observable<Leaf>{  
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/',{ headers: headers ...})
        .map(res =>new Leaf(res.json()));//maybe I could do something here?
}
```

and here is my Leaf class just in case:

**Leaf.ts**

```
export class Leaf{
    name: string;
    state: string;
    treeData: Array<Leaf>;


    constructor(input:any){
        this.name = input.name;
        this.state = input.state;
        this.treeData = input.children;
    }

    toggleState() {
        if (this.state=='active'){
            this.state = 'inactive';
        }
        else {
            this.state = 'active'
        }
    }
}
```

My final goal is to get the json tree and represent them in a folder tree format. Is there a way to use map() to go through all nodes or combination of map() and some sort of traverser?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I cast a JSON object to a typescript class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875636/how-do-i-cast-a-json-object-to-a-typescript-class)

Comment: I had seen that question but my question here was how to take care of the nested tree and the recursive nature of my data. Although there are some overlap between the two questions I think, my question is asking for something specific to nested tree while the other is more broad on casting json. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd first create an interface for the json data:

```
interface LeafJson {
    name: string;
    state: string;
    children?: LeafJson[];
}
```

And then use Array.map to create the children:

```
export class Leaf {
    name: string;
    state: string;
    treeData: Array<Leaf>;

    constructor(input: LeafJson){
        this.name = input.name;
        this.state = input.state;
        this.treeData = input.children ? input.children.map(item => new Leaf(item)) : [];
    }

    toggleState() {
        if (this.state=='active'){
            this.state = 'inactive';
        } else {
            this.state = 'active'
        }
    }
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20LeafJson%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20state%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20children%3F%3A%20LeafJson%5B%5D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aexport%20class%20Leaf%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20state%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20treeData%3A%20Array%3CLeaf%3E%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(input%3A%20LeafJson)%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.name%20%3D%20input.name%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.state%20%3D%20input.state%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.treeData%20%3D%20input.children%20%3F%20input.children.map(item%20%3D%3E%20new%20Leaf(item))%20%3A%20%5B%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20toggleState()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(this.state%3D%3D'active')%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.state%20%3D%20'inactive'%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.state%20%3D%20'active'%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D))

Comment: Splendid ! Thanks

Comment: This didn't run for me until I removed the `export` from the class definition (got a weird browser error).  Otherwise, thanks for answer!~

Comment: @AdamHughes yeah, that's in case you're using a module system, as the OP.