# How to parse a JSON object to a TypeScript Object

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am currently trying to convert my received JSON Object into a TypeScript class with the same attributes and I cannot get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

**Employee Class**

```
export class Employee{
    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;
    birthdate: Date;
    maxWorkHours: number;
    department: string;
    permissions: string;
    typeOfEmployee: string;
    note: string;
    lastUpdate: Date;
}
```

**Employee String**

```
{
    "department": "<anystring>",
    "typeOfEmployee": "<anystring>",
    "firstname": "<anystring>",
    "lastname": "<anystring>",
    "birthdate": "<anydate>",
    "maxWorkHours": <anynumber>,
    "username": "<anystring>",
    "permissions": "<anystring>",
    "lastUpdate": "<anydate>"
    //I will add note later
}
```

**My Attempt**

```
let e: Employee = new Employee();

Object.assign(e, {
    "department": "<anystring>",
    "typeOfEmployee": "<anystring>",
    "firstname": "<anystring>",
    "lastname": "<anystring>",
    "birthdate": "<anydate>",
    "maxWorkHours": 3,
    "username": "<anystring>",
    "permissions": "<anystring>",
    "lastUpdate": "<anydate>"
});

console.log(e);
```

[Link to Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Employee%7B%0A%20%20%20%20firstname%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20lastname%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20birthdate%3A%20Date%3B%0A%20%20%20%20maxWorkHours%3A%20number%3B%0A%20%20%20%20department%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20permissions%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20typeOfEmployee%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20note%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20lastUpdate%3A%20Date%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20e%3A%20Employee%20%3D%20new%20Employee()%3B%0AObject.assign(e%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22department%22%3A%20%22%3Canystring%3E%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22typeOfEmployee%22%3A%20%22%3Canystring%3E%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22firstname%22%3A%20%22%3Canystring%3E%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22lastname%22%3A%20%22%3Canystring%3E%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22birthdate%22%3A%20%22%3Canydate%3E%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22maxWorkHours%22%3A%203%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22username%22%3A%20%22%3Canystring%3E%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22permissions%22%3A%20%22%3Canystring%3E%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22lastUpdate%22%3A%20%22%3Canydate%3E%22%0A%7D)%3B%0Aconsole.log(e)%3B%0A)

Comment: What's not working exactly? It's not compiling? If so, what's the error?

Comment: Edited my question. It works now but the object is not recognized as Employee, only as Object.

Comment: Check this [gist](https://gist.github.com/goenning/a4caf5f31c22716dcdbd0e5814313502) and try it on the [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play). The `employee` variable has both properties available.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I cast a JSON object to a typescript class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875636/how-do-i-cast-a-json-object-to-a-typescript-class)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The reason that the compiler lets you cast the object returned from `JSON.parse` to a class is because [typescript is based on structural subtyping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html).
You don't really have an instance of an `Employee`, you have an object (as you see in the console) which has the same properties.

A simpler example:

```
class A {
    constructor(public str: string, public num: number) {}
}

function logA(a: A) {
    console.log(`A instance with str: "${ a.str }" and num: ${ a.num }`);
}

let a1 = { str: "string", num: 0, boo: true };
let a2 = new A("stirng", 0);
logA(a1); // no errors
logA(a2);
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(public%20str%3A%20string%2C%20public%20num%3A%20number)%20%7B%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20logA(a%3A%20A)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(%60A%20instance%20with%20str%3A%20%22%24%7B%20a.str%20%7D%22%20and%20num%3A%20%24%7B%20a.num%20%7D%60)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20a1%20%3D%20%7B%20str%3A%20%22string%22%2C%20num%3A%200%2C%20boo%3A%20true%20%7D%3B%0Alet%20a2%20%3D%20new%20A(%22stirng%22%2C%200)%3B%0AlogA(a1)%3B%20%2F%2F%20no%20errors%0AlogA(a2)%3B))

There's no error because `a1` satisfies type `A` because it has all of its properties, and the `logA` function can be called with no runtime errors even if what it receives isn't an instance of `A` as long as it has the same properties.

That works great when your classes are simple data objects and have no methods, but once you introduce methods then things tend to break:

```
class A {
    constructor(public str: string, public num: number) { }

    multiplyBy(x: number): number {
        return this.num * x;
    }
}

// this won't compile:
let a1 = { str: "string", num: 0, boo: true } as A; // Error: Type '{ str: string; num: number; boo: boolean; }' cannot be converted to type 'A'

// but this will:
let a2 = { str: "string", num: 0 } as A;

// and then you get a runtime error:
a2.multiplyBy(4); // Error: Uncaught TypeError: a2.multiplyBy is not a function
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(public%20str%3A%20string%2C%20public%20num%3A%20number)%20%7B%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20multiplyBy(x%3A%20number)%3A%20number%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.num%20*%20x%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20a1%20%3D%20%7B%20str%3A%20%22string%22%2C%20num%3A%200%2C%20boo%3A%20true%20%7D%20as%20A%3B%20%2F%2F%20Error%3A%20Type%20'%7B%20str%3A%20string%3B%20num%3A%20number%3B%20boo%3A%20boolean%3B%20%7D'%20cannot%20be%20converted%20to%20type%20'A'%0Alet%20a2%20%3D%20%7B%20str%3A%20%22string%22%2C%20num%3A%200%20%7D%20as%20A%3B%0A%0Aa2.multiplyBy(4)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Error%3A%20Uncaught%20TypeError%3A%20a2.multiplyBy%20is%20not%20a%20function))

---

#### Edit

This works just fine:

```
const employeeString = '{"department":"<anystring>","typeOfEmployee":"<anystring>","firstname":"<anystring>","lastname":"<anystring>","birthdate":"<anydate>","maxWorkHours":0,"username":"<anystring>","permissions":"<anystring>","lastUpdate":"<anydate>"}';
let employee1 = JSON.parse(employeeString);
console.log(employee1);
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=const%20employeeString%20%3D%20'%7B%22department%22%3A%22%3Canystring%3E%22%2C%22typeOfEmployee%22%3A%22%3Canystring%3E%22%2C%22firstname%22%3A%22%3Canystring%3E%22%2C%22lastname%22%3A%22%3Canystring%3E%22%2C%22birthdate%22%3A%22%3Canydate%3E%22%2C%22maxWorkHours%22%3A0%2C%22username%22%3A%22%3Canystring%3E%22%2C%22permissions%22%3A%22%3Canystring%3E%22%2C%22lastUpdate%22%3A%22%3Canydate%3E%22%7D'%3B%0Alet%20employee1%20%3D%20JSON.parse(employeeString)%3B%0Aconsole.log(employee1)%3B))

If you're trying to use `JSON.parse` on your object when it's not a string:

```
let e = {
    "department": "<anystring>",
    "typeOfEmployee": "<anystring>",
    "firstname": "<anystring>",
    "lastname": "<anystring>",
    "birthdate": "<anydate>",
    "maxWorkHours": 3,
    "username": "<anystring>",
    "permissions": "<anystring>",
    "lastUpdate": "<anydate>"
}
let employee2 = JSON.parse(e);
```

Then you'll get the error because it's not a string, it's an object, and if you already have it in this form then there's no need to use `JSON.parse`.

But, as I wrote, if you're going with this way then you won't have an instance of the class, just an object that has the same properties as the class members.

If you want an instance then:

```
let e = new Employee();
Object.assign(e, {
    "department": "<anystring>",
    "typeOfEmployee": "<anystring>",
    "firstname": "<anystring>",
    "lastname": "<anystring>",
    "birthdate": "<anydate>",
    "maxWorkHours": 3,
    "username": "<anystring>",
    "permissions": "<anystring>",
    "lastUpdate": "<anydate>"
});
```

Comment: So i basically can cast any object string to an object or interface if it has the same (but it must not have all) properties as the object or interface? And this works for both. But if I need methods I have to use a class instead of an interface and than I can only call the methods of my classes objects is they were made through the constructor of the class. Right? And if can change my employee class to an interface rightaway because I just need it for typisation?

Comment: But can I also cast an object string to an object or interface if the string has more properties than the object? Because in my case this is not working.

Comment: I just looked closer to my result of JSON.parse(employeeString) and I saw that it has an additional property Symbol(rxSubscriber)_m.crflse0mxkc which is undefined and I did not send but it is there after parsing. I also get errors when my JSON string is missing properties my object/interface has. This is not the behavior you explained above or am I wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "object string", please elaborate on that. As for the additional properties you have in your object after `JSON.parse` it looks like rx added something into it, not sure at what point, as I have no idea what you're doing and what you're using. Last thing: what errors do you get? do you get them in compilation time or runtime? Please update your question with relevant code and error messages.

Comment: The object string is an Employee object which gets stringified on the server and then sent to my web app where it should be an object of the employee class there again. Is this enough information or do you need more? I also edited my question with attempts and error.

Comment: Check my revised answer

Comment: If I do it like in your example with the new instance I end up with an object which has every character as a own property or so. I edited my question with the error.

Comment: I can't understand what you mean. Please update your question with this info and explain what you did and what you got back

Comment: Sorry I commented before updating. Was doing it just at the moment.

Comment: Using your exact code I get: `Employee {department: "<anystring>", typeOfEmployee: "<anystring>", firstname: "<anystring>", lastname: "<anystring>", birthdate: "<anydate>"…}` which is fine

Comment: Ok now it works. But it still throws me this error: `Argument of type 'Employee' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.` And it prints as [Object object] which means to me that is a random object and not one of my specific class.

Comment: I don't get that at all. Are you sure that the code you posted in the question (in your edit) is exactly what you're trying to run? Go to the typescript playground, reproduce the problem there and then share that playground in your question.

Comment: Yes I am. As employee string I am not even using data from the server anymore. Just the thing you used in you answer.

Comment: Post a playground link

Comment: In playground it works but I can not get it to work in my program.

Comment: If it works in playground then it works.  If it fails in your local environment then you have a completely different problem.  I suggest that you ask a new question about it.

Comment: Ok I will do so. I was so sure I failed in typescript. Thank you for your help anyways I will keep on trying.

Answer (score 72):

If you use a [TypeScript *interface*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#defining-types) instead of a *class*, things are simpler:

```js
export interface Employee {
    typeOfEmployee_id: number;
    department_id: number;
    permissions_id: number;
    maxWorkHours: number;
    employee_id: number;
    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;
    username: string;
    birthdate: Date;
    lastUpdate: Date;
}

let jsonObj = JSON.parse(employeeString); // string to "any" object first
let employee = jsonObj as Employee;
```

If you want a *class*, however, simple casting won't work. For example:

```js
class Foo {
    name: string;
    public pump() { }
}

let jsonObj = JSON.parse('{ "name":"hello" }');
let fObj = jsonObj as Foo;
fObj.pump(); // crash, method is undefined!
```

For a class, you'll have to write a constructor which accepts a JSON string/object and then iterate through the properties to assign each member manually, like this:

```js
class Foo {
    name: string;

    constructor(jsonStr: string) {
        let jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
        for (let prop in jsonObj) {
            this[prop] = jsonObj[prop];
        }
    }
}

let fObj = new Foo(theJsonString);
```

Comment: This seems logical to me. I just saw that my JSON Converter at the source sends the id's because the employee class there has got them. But it should send the values which the id's point at. I will adjust that and than try to cast it like in your example.

Comment: I adjusted the json string and updated my question above. I also implemented your solution but it is still not recognized as Employee and throws a type mismatch error.

Comment: @moessi774 I just updated me answer, I guess I exactly understood your question now.

Comment: I did not know about interfaces for now. So if I just use my class for typisation a interface would be much smarter. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: This good answer is from 2016. With ES6 you can use Object.assign(this, input) inside a function in your object to avoid manually iterating the properties. You still need to take care of object nesting manually, though.

Comment: @Rodrigo Does the solution with interface work when I have nested objects?

Comment: @Keselme In theory, yes.

Comment: @rodrigocfd what if my interface has fewer fields compared to what is present in the json object

Answer (score 7):

```
let employee = <Employee>JSON.parse(employeeString);
```

Remember: Strong typings is compile time only since javascript doesn't support it.

Comment: What's the difference between your example and his?

Answer (score 6):

Your JSON data may have some properties that you do not have in your class. For mapping You can do simple custom mapping

```
export class Employe{ ////
    static parse(json: string) {
           var data = JSON.parse(json);
            return new Employe(data.typeOfEmployee_id, data.firstName.. and others);
       }
}
```

and also specifying constructor in your `Employee` class.

Comment: This looks like a good solution. I try it some more times with my current way. If it is still not working I implement yours.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to be sure that all attributes of that comes from the service are named the same in your class. Then you can parse the object and after that assign it to your new variable, something like this:

```
const parsedJSON = JSON.parse(serverResponse);
const employeeObj: Employee = parsedJSON as Employee;
```

Try that!

Comment: This solution has one big problem - not support to nested object

Answer (score 2):

i like to use a littly tiny library called [class-transformer](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer).

it can handle nested-objects, map strings to date-objects and handle different json-property-names a lot more.

Maybe worth a look.

````js
import { Type, plainToClass, Expose } from "class-transformer";
import 'reflect-metadata';

export class Employee{
    @Expose({ name: "uid" })
    id: number;

    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;
    birthdate: Date;
    maxWorkHours: number;
    department: string;

    @Type(() => Permission)
    permissions: Permission[] = [];
    typeOfEmployee: string;
    note: string;

    @Type(() => Date)
    lastUpdate: Date;
}

export class Permission {
  type : string;
}

let json:string = {
    "uid": 123,
    "department": "<anystring>",
    "typeOfEmployee": "<anystring>",
    "firstname": "<anystring>",
    "lastname": "<anystring>",
    "birthdate": "<anydate>",
    "maxWorkHours": 1,
    "username": "<anystring>",
    "permissions": [
      {'type' : 'read'},
      {'type' : 'write'}
    ],
    "lastUpdate": "2020-05-08"
}

console.log(plainToClass(Employee, json));

```
````

Comment: Agreed. For non-trivial cases with nested object hierarchies, class-transformer is a useful tool that greatly reduces the amount of manual deserialization code required for an app that sends/receives external data in JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use constructor procedure in your class.

> Object.assign

is a key

Please take a look on this sample:

```
class Employee{
    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;
    birthdate: Date;
    maxWorkHours: number;
    department: string;
    permissions: string;
    typeOfEmployee: string;
    note: string;
    lastUpdate: Date;

    constructor(original: Object) { 
        Object.assign(this, original);
    }
}

let e = new Employee({
    "department": "<anystring>",
    "typeOfEmployee": "<anystring>",
    "firstname": "<anystring>",
    "lastname": "<anystring>",
    "birthdate": "<anydate>",
    "maxWorkHours": 3,
    "username": "<anystring>",
    "permissions": "<anystring>",
    "lastUpdate": "<anydate>"
});
console.log(e);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the the json as follows:

Given your class:

```
export class Employee{
    firstname: string= '';
}
```

and the json:

```
let jsonObj = {
    "firstname": "Hesham"
};
```

You can cast it as follows:

```
let e: Employee = jsonObj as Employee;
```

And the output of `console.log(e);` is:

> { firstname: 'Hesham' }

Answer (score 0):

you can make a new object of your class and then assign it's parameters dynamically from the JSON object's parameters.

```
const employeeData = JSON.parse(employeeString);
let emp:Employee=new Employee();
const keys=Object.keys(employeeData);
keys.forEach(key=>{
    emp[key]=employeeData[key];
});
console.log(emp);
```

now the emp is an object of Employee containing all fields of employeeString's Json object(employeeData);

Answer (score 0):

You can perform this operation using syntax "as"?

```
async getProfile(): Promise<Contact> {
      const url: string = this.baseApi;
    
      const response = await this.http.get(url).toPromise()
      return JSON.parse(response.json()) as Contact;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a concise solution that works well for simple "flat" objects:

```
let listOfObjectsWithMethods = listFromBackend.map( o => Object.assign(new MyType(), o));
```

Once you perform this transformation, you will be able to access the methods of objects declared in the MyType class

Answer (score -3):

```
if it is coming from server as object you can do
```

this.service.subscribe(data:any) keep any type on data it will solve the issue

Comment: 'Any' type is variable, when I get a wrong object, it may be necessary to do a lot of if checks below.  The object may not be parsed correctly or there may be a missing property.

Comment: You should use json parse instead.  Json.parse returns any type, but can be converted to an object using the 'as'syntax.