# Typescript JSON to Class with "es5"

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

What is the best/common way to cast a **JSON** into a class in **Typescript** with **ES5** (no `Object.assign()`).

e.g.

```
export class Lesson{
 name:string;
 teacher:Teacher;
 date:Date;
 scholars:Array<string>; //or string[] ... I dont care
}
```

The JSON would look like:

```
{
 name:"LessonName",
 teacher:{name:"masterT", age:120},
 date:12345678912
 scholars:["Jim","Bob","Jimbo"]
}
```

In Typescript I can cast the JSON to a Object and even assign it straight to a Lesson object **(!-horrible behaviour, but thats JS-!)**

But the object don't have any methods for example.

e.g. So `lesson.date.getTime()` won't work.

So how to handle that correctly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I initialize a typescript object with a JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22885995/how-do-i-initialize-a-typescript-object-with-a-json-object)

Comment: This is the job for the `constructor` of a class. This way you can cast the date field into a Date object etc so you can do `new Lesson(attributes)`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
// first declare variable
var lesson: Lesson;

// and then assign that
lesson={
 name:"LessonName",
 teacher:{name:"masterT", age:120},
 date:12345678912
 scholars:["Jim","Bob","Jimbo"]
}
```

But the problem is that you want to put only a value in an object.

Comment: This is not valid TypeScript, nor does it answer the question properly (for instance, the `date` property is not a `Date` object.)

Comment: But `lesson` is still not an instance of the `Lesson` class.  You need to do something like `lesson = new Lesson()`, and then start setting properties.  And `date` is still not a `Date`.  Sorry, but this is not a proper answer.

Comment: you can also see there, same problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40421100/how-to-parse-a-json-object-to-a-typescript-object

Comment: You can also use this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/serializer.ts

Comment: Yeah, it seem I cant avoid manual code here. -Again: Object.assign() ist not available. Nor it helps lot with encapsuled classes.