# How to fetch value from array which came from json in Angular 5 app?

Tags: arrays, json, angular

I have the following JSON definitions:

```
 export class Company {
      name: string;
      trips : Trip[] = [];
    }

export class Trip{
    id: number;
    name: string;        
}
```

I am able to see the trips in the console using:

```
console.log(this.company);
```

In the component I have the following method:

```
if(this.company) {
     Object.keys(this.company.trips).forEach((data) => {     
            console.log(data);                        
        });
}
```

What I am getting in the console is the trip's properties names which is "id" and "number".
I would like to know how to access the value.

Comment: why are you using `Object.keys`?

Comment: `this.company.trips.forEach(trip => { console.log('trip.id', trip.id })`

Comment: *"What I am getting in the console is the trip's properties names which is "id" and "number"."* That's odd. You've said it's an *array*. The keys of an array are numeric strings (`"0"`, `"1"`, etc.), not things like `"id"` and `"number"`.

Comment: On a side note: If these are representations of data coming from an api, I would strongly suggest  that you make these interfaces instead, because these will not be instances of the class. You might be falling into a problem of testing for a constructor (`instanceof`) and not get what you expect.

Comment: `Object.keys` gives you the names of the own, enumerable, String-named properties of the object. If you want the values, you can use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) which returns an array of the values of those properties. If you want both, you can use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) which returns an array of `[key, value]` arrays. Normally, though, you know the shape of the object and use its properties directly.

Comment: I've changed from keys to values and now I am to see the values but I get both id and name I need only the value of the name. Any idea how to access ?

Answer (score 0):

According to your data structure, you should not even try to do `Object.keys` what you should be doing as the `Trip` is an object, is something like following in which you treat the iteration object as a real `Trip` object

```html
if(this.company && this.company.trips){
this.company.trips.forEach((trip:Trip) => {     
            console.log(trip.id + '\n' + trip.name);                        
        });
}
```

if you have any issue with this piece of cod then make sure you are correctly doing your deserialization process and objects are getting cast properly.

Comment: I'm getting ERROR TypeError: this.company.trips.forEach is not a function

Comment: @user2304483 then you are facing the casting issue as I thought. there is a library for casting I guess it might be a good idea to give it a go. https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer

Comment: you might also take a look at this tread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35969974/foreach-is-not-a-function-error-with-javascript-array

Comment: you mean the trips is not coming as array from the api ?

Comment: No I mean the deserialization problems in Angular side when you try deserialize JSON coming from server to objects

Comment: I've changed the code to cast to array and now I'm getting the values {id: 1, name: "ABC"} but I need to access only the name. I need way to fetch only the name. This is the current code:  if(this.company) {
      const parent = this.company;
      console.log(parent.trips);
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(parent.trips, child => {
        console.log(child)
      });
    }

Comment: have you tried doing a cast on the child like: `Array.prototype.forEach.call(parent.trips, (child:Trip) => { console.log(child.name) }); }` ?

Comment: if this also doesn't work then you should convert the child in the execution code with any method you know, such as the ones you can find here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40421100/how-to-parse-a-json-object-to-a-typescript-object

Comment: it doesn't work I still get the full Trip object. Do I need to change something in the Trip class to make it work ?

Comment: can you make a working version on stack blitz so I can take a look?

Comment: I don't think so because the object is coming from API.

Comment: well, you could just fake your service with 3-4 data in a JSON string. the problem is I don't get it why you should get `{id: 1, name: "ABC"}` on the normal loop but the casting to Trip is not working. usually when you have `{id: 1, name: "ABC"}`  and you cast to `Trip` the child should be a real `Trip` object that you can do `child.name`

Comment: I actually don't get nothing, the console.log(child) doesn't work

Comment: but you just said: "I've changed the code to cast to array and now I'm getting the values {id: 1, name: "ABC"} but I need to access only the name. " I don't understand. let's do something, can you copy here the json for 2 companies so I can make a stackblitz example for you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188919/discussion-between-user2304483-and-thriller).

Comment: I had a console.log before the loop, that's why I said that, I'm still with tis problem