# Convert Json to Object in Angular 7

Tags: json, angular7

This is json string {"firstName":"John" ,"lastName":"Doe" }.
I would like to convert json string to object with custom name in angular.This is c# code.

```
public class Example
{ 
    [JsonProperty("firstName")]
    public string FName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("lastName")]
    public string LName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Try the below link,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40421100/how-to-parse-a-json-object-to-a-typescript-object

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Angular. This is all about how to get your .NET API to serialise your models with custom naming attributes.

Answer (score 2):

Just use JSON.parse

```js
console.log(JSON.parse('{"firstName":"John" ,"lastName":"Doe" }'))
```

But you shouldn't have to. How are you getting the JSON string? If you made a call to your C# api with the HttpClient like

```
http.get<YourModel>('apiUrl');
```

The response from the api should already be parsed as long as the api responded with a content type of text/json.

Comment: but i want to rename FName instead of firstName and LName instead of lastName

Comment: You have to do that serverside in your api, Angular will not get those C# attributes sent across the wire.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a front-end model, use the classToPlain method of the lib class-transformer  https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer

Example

```
import { classToPlain } from "class-transformer";
...
var yourModel: YourModel = {"firstName":"John" ,"lastName":"Doe" };
this.http.post(`${url}/AnyMethod`, classToPlain(yourModel)).pipe();
...

class YourModel{
   firstName: string;
   lastName: string;
}
```