# Getting [object Object] while mapping http response in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core, angular-services

I am getting an [object Object] while using Observable map in angular 2.

Here is the response object from the API service.

```
{
  "isSuccess": true,
  "message": "Connection Successfull",
  "data": [
    {
      "marketId": 1,
      "city": "san",
      "cityF": "san",
      "name": null,
      "nameF": "hello",
      "sortOrder": 1,
      "isActive": true
    },
    {
      "marketId": 2,
      "city": "san",
      "cityF": "san",
      "name": null,
      "nameF": "hello",
      "sortOrder": 1,
      "isActive": true
    },
    {
      "marketId": 3,
      "city": "san",
      "cityF": "san",
      "name": null,
      "nameF": "hello",
      "sortOrder": 1,
      "isActive": true
    },
    {
      "marketId": 4,
      "city": "san",
      "cityF": "san",
      "name": null,
      "nameF": "hello",
      "sortOrder": 1,
      "isActive": true
    }
  ],
  "exceptionErrorMessage": null,
  "errorCode": 0,
  "successMessage": null
}
```

Here is the model I have created to map with the response.

```
export class MarketViewModel 
{
public isSuccess: boolean;
public message : string;
public successMessage : string;
public exceptionErrorMessage : string;
public errorCode: number;
public data: MarketListObject[];

}
export class MarketListObject 
{
    public marketId : number;
    public city: string;
    public cityF : string;
    public name : string;
    public nameF : string;
    public sortOrder : number;
    public isActive : boolean; 
}
```

Service class to call the http and map the response.

```
import { Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { MarketViewModel} from "../ViewModel/Market.ViewModel";
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Injectable()
export class DashBoardService {
    private MarketUrl = "DashBoard/GetMarketList";
    private ResponseData: any;
    constructor(private http: Http, private router: Router, private  marketModel : MarketViewModel) {}

    public GetMarketListCall() :Observable<MarketViewModel> {
         return this.http.get(this.MarketUrl).map(this.extractData)
                    .catch(this.handleError);
    } 
private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
        console.log("Body Data = "+body.data);
    return body.data || { };
  }
```

Here is the Component.ts which is calling Service.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MarketViewModel} from "../ViewModel/Market.ViewModel";
import { DashBoardService} from "../Service/DashBoard.Service";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

 @Component({
     selector: 'Market-app',
    templateUrl: 'DashBoard/MarketListView',
    providers: [DashBoardService, MarketViewModel]
 })

export class MarketComponent {
  constructor(private DashBoardservice: DashBoardService, private  marketModel : MarketViewModel) {
   }

ngOnInit() {
        this.DashBoardservice.GetMarketListCall().subscribe(
                               data => {this.marketModel = data;
                                    console.log("this"+this.marketModel); }, 
                                err => {console.log(err);});
}
}
```

When I see to the console I am getting **[object Object]** response. Where is the mistake I am not able to figure it out

Comment: You are appending the objects to a string here- `console.log("Body Data = "+body.data);` ... Try this instead - `console.log("Body Data = ", body.data);` . And the same thing at `"this"+this.marketModel)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change your `DashBoardService` as below as you are have to return `MarketListObject` array as observable not `MarketViewModel` :

```
@Injectable()
export class DashBoardService {
  private MarketUrl = "DashBoard/GetMarketList";
  private ResponseData: any;

  constructor(private http: Http, private router: Router, private  marketModel : MarketViewModel) {}

  public GetMarketListCall() :Observable<MarketListObject[]> {
     return this.http.get(this.MarketUrl).map(this.extractData)
                .catch(this.handleError);
  } 

  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    console.log("Body Data = "+body.data);
    return body.data || [];
  }
}
```

Also there is no need to pass `MarketViewModel` as providers inside `MarketComponent` so remove `MarketViewModel` from `MarketComponent` providers list and change your component as below .

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DashBoardService} from "../Service/DashBoard.Service";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'Market-app',
  templateUrl: 'DashBoard/MarketListView',
  providers: [DashBoardService]
})
export class MarketComponent {

  public marketList: any[];

  constructor(private dashBoardservice: DashBoardService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dashBoardservice.GetMarketListCall().subscribe((data) => { 
      this.marketList = data;
      console.log("this" + this.marketList);
    },(err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: It didn't work for me .. I am getting [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: Inside `extractData` function or inside `ngOnInit` of `MarketComponent` ?
also check by removing `:Observable<MarketListObject[]>` from `GetMarketListCall` functions return type.

Comment: If I use subscribe in service then everything works fine. When I used map I am getting a object. Yeah I check in ngOnInit. I am still getting object

Comment: i have updated component in my answer. inside component `marketList` variable should be array of `MarketListObject` like `public marketList: MarketListObject[]` so import it and change it if it required otherwise `any[]` will also work.

Comment: Can you please let me know how to map with the class as the response from the web api class.I dont want direct array. I want to map with the object

Comment: Try to check with `public GetMarketListCall() { return this.http.get(this.MarketUrl).map((res) => res.json()).catch(this.handleError); }` in service and `console.log(data)` inside subscribe code of `GetMarketListCall` API call inside your component

Answer (score 4):

You have a problem with your `extractData`, you want the response as it is, to match your `MarketViewModel`, so you need to remove the `data` from that method and also to return an empty object if there is no response:

```
private extractData(res: Response) {
  let body = res.json();
  return body || {};
}
```

Some pointers:

- In your Service and MarketComponent you do not need to inject the
  MarketViewModel in your constructor.
- You need to declare a variable `marketModel` in your component, to be
  able to use `this.marketModel`.
- In component you have declared method `ngOnInit`, but not implemented it in your component

When testing your app it worked:

```
getMarketListCall(): Observable<MarketViewModel>{
    return this.http.get('theUrl')
        .map(res => res.json()) // or use the 'extractData'
        // .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Your component:

```
marketmodel: MarketViewModel

ngOnInit() {
    this.DashBoarservice.GetMarketListCall()
       .subscribe(data => {
          this.marketModel = data;
        },
        err => { console.log(err); 
    });
}
```

Your view, you should wrap your html in an if-statement, since your data gets retrieved asynchronously:

e.g:

```html
<div *ngIf="marketModel"> <!-- Here! -->
  <h2>MarketModel Message: {{marketModel.message}}</h2>
  <div *ngFor="let data of marketModel.data">Id: {{data.marketId}} </div>
</div><br>
```

We need to remember though this code works wonderfully, we have not actually casted the response to be of instances of your classes. If you wish to do that, I suggest the following link with some great answers :) [How do I cast a JSON object to a typescript class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875636/how-do-i-cast-a-json-object-to-a-typescript-class)

Comment: I am getting an error as ...  Can't resolve all parameters for MarketViewModel: (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?).

Comment: Hmmm, strange, worked perfectly for me. At what point do you get the error?

Comment: Working plunker here: https://plnkr.co/edit/H73JV0kncx0tV0NIFMPx?p=preview

Comment: Don't use classes to define these types. use interfaces.