# Error [object Object]

Tags: json, angular, typescript

Okay so I am running angular 2, and I am just trying to log a simple JSON object in the console but I get this [image]

**UPDATE...**

I have provided my error log below

[image]

I have looked on a fair few posts and people have similar issues e.g

[Getting [object Object] while mapping http response in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41627548/getting-object-object-while-mapping-http-response-in-angular-2)

I have changed a few things around but still no dice!

Firstly here is my items2.json

```
{
  "Company": {
    "company_details": [
      {
        "test": "test"
      }
    ],
    "success": true
  }
}
```

My model ... 'company.ts'

```
export interface Company {
  company_details : CompanyDetails[];
  success : boolean;
}

export interface CompanyDetails {
  test: string;
}
```

Here is my component:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Company} from "./models/test/company";
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

  title = 'Test angular';

  constructor(private http : HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.http.get<Company>('http://localhost:4200/assets/items2.json')
             .subscribe( data => console.log(data.company_details)
    );
  }   
}
```

Why I am receiving this error? how do I fix it ?

Thanks

Comment: Try check if this works. 
    
`this.http.get("http://localhost:4200/assets/api/items2.json").map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
    (data) => console.log(data.company_details),
    (err) => console.log(err)
);`

Or if it throws an erro

Comment: Okay added it, thanks!

Comment: Is it working or what happens when you go to `http://localhost:4200/assets/api/items2.json` directly

Comment: @pritesh https://ibb.co/fUocpb , check that image. It outputs the JSON object

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer, it turns out the InMemoryDataService for the InMemoryWebApi, Interferes with Http, I have turned it off in my app.module.ts and it is now working.

Reference:

[Angular2 / Error: Collection not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39085512/angular2-error-collection-not-found)