# How do I cast a JSON object to a typescript class when properties doesn't match?

Tags: json, angular, typescript

For example, I have a class:

```
export class SomeClass {
 id: number;
 name: string;
}
```

I receive JSON from server than looks like this

```
[{"Id":1,"Name":"typicalname"},{"Id":2,"Name":"somename"},{"Id":3,"Name":"blablabla"},{"Id":4,"Name":"lol"},{"Id":5,"Name":"lil"},{"Id":6,"Name":"lal"}]
```

How do I cast a JSON object to a typescript class when properties doesn't match?
That's how I do it wright now, and it's not working.

```
getSomeClass() {
  return this.http.get(this.someClassUrl)
    .map(response => <SomeClass[]>response.json())
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Comment: potential duplicate of  [http://stackoverflow.com/q/22875636/1160236](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22875636/1160236)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I cast a JSON object to a typescript class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875636/how-do-i-cast-a-json-object-to-a-typescript-class)

Comment: @HirenParekh I saw that question, but I wasn't found what to do, when properties doesn't match.

Comment: Using a class is a very bad practice here since `instanceof` will fail at runtime is anyone tries to use it (hint use `interface` not `class`). You need to manually write a function that verifies the shape of the deserialized object in order to validate it.

Comment: Also, what is `handleError`? If it is a method on the service that uses `this`, passing it as shown will fail. If it does not use `this` why is it a member of the class?

Comment: you can try this [class-transformer](https://github.com/pleerock/class-transformer) library

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
getSomeClass() {
  return this.http.get(this.someClassUrl)
    .map(response => {
        let json = response.json();
        return json.map(m => {
            return {
                id: json.Id,
                name: json.Name
            }
        }
    })
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Comment: This does not do what is asked for. It does not validate the deserialized object.

Comment: @AluanHaddad actually, the OP explicitly mentioned that the "properties don't match"; so the question is not about validation.

Comment: That is not how I interpreted it, but at any rate the function should modify the OP by not returning something declared as a class since that is misleading given the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a type `T` and a value `x` and you write `<T>x` you are not performing a cast in a runtime sense. You are performing a type assertion. What this means is that you are telling TypeScript that the type of `x` is `T`.

In this particular case, if `response.json()` returns a value typed as `any`, which is not unreasonable for a deserialization operation, then `<T>response.json()` will be accepted by the TypeScript compiler for any `T`. This is because the type `any` is compatible with (technically assignable to) everything.

However in this case you want to verify the shape of the response and the compiler cannot do this for you. You need to write a validation algorithm that is appropriate.

What is appropriate will depend on the domain of your application, and may be non-trivial, but here is an example. Unfortunately, since your question implies Angular 2 and RxJS, even a simple applicable answer contains a fair amount of incidental complexity.

```
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

function injected(_) {} // emit decorator metadata with flag (not pertinent)

@injected export class SomeService {

  constructor(readonly http: Http) {}

  getSomeValue(): Observable<Expected> {
   return this.http.get(this.someResourceUrl)
      .catch(handleError)
      .mergeMap(response => {
        const deserialized = response.json();
        if (isExpected(deserialized)) {
          // note the type of derserialized is Expected in this block
          return Observable.of(deserialized);
        }
        return Observable.throw('response data did not have the expected shape');
      });
  }
}

export interface Expected {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

function isExpected(deserialized : any): deserialized is Expected {
  return typeof deserialized.id === 'number' && typeof deserialized.name === 'string';
}

function handleError(error) { // this is not really necessary, but was in the question
  console.error(error); // log
  return Observable.throw(error); // rethrow.
}
```

The most significant thing here is the `isExpected` function.

It takes a value of any type, validates it based on our criteria, and states that if it returns true, then the given value was indeed of the expected type, `Expected`.

What does it mean to be of the expected type?

Well our `isExpected` function determines that, and provides this information to the TypeScript language by way of its return type which says that if the function returns true, then the value passed to it is of type `Expected`.

This is known as a User Defined Type Guard function and you can read more about it at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html.