# Json to Object deeply

Tags: json, angular, typescript

In my TypeScript code I have 2 classes `ClassA` and `ClassB`:

```
export class ClassA {
    name: string;
    classB: ClassB;

    getName(): string {
        return this.name;
    }
}

export class ClassB {
    name: string;

    getName(): string {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

I try to parse a Json into a `ClassA` instance like this:

```
let classA: ClassA = Object.assign(new ClassA(), JSON.parse('{"name":"classA", "classB": {"name":"classB"}}'));
```

But only `ClassA` is instanciated, inside classB attribute is not.

I have the following result when I log objects:

```
console.log(classA); // ClassA {name: "classA", classB: Object}
console.log(classA.getName()); // classA
console.log(classA.classB); // Object {name: "classB"}
console.log(classA.classB.getName()); // EXCEPTION: classA.classB.getName is not a function
```

Is that possible to deeply parse a Json?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I cast a JSON object to a typescript class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875636/how-do-i-cast-a-json-object-to-a-typescript-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, the best way I found is to do:

```
export class ClassA {
    name: string;
    classB: ClassB;

    constructor(json: any) {
        this.name = json.name;
        if (json.classB !== undefined && json.classB !== null) {
            this.classB = new ClassB(json.classB);
        }
    }
}

export class ClassB {
    name: string;

    constructor(json: any) {
        this.name = json.name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do something like this:

```
export interface ClassBData {
    name: string;
}

export interface ClassAData {
    name: string;
    classB: ClassBData;
}

export class ClassA {
    name: string;
    classB: ClassB;

    constructor(json: ClassAData) {
        this.name = json.name;
        this.classB = Object.assign(new ClassB(), json.classB);
    }

    getName(): string {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Or you can instantiate `ClassB` the same way:

```
export class ClassB {
    name: string;

    constructor(json: ClassBData) {
        this.name = json.name;
    }

    getName(): string {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```