# Typescript method on class undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

In Typescript I have a class `Contact` which implements an interface `IContact`.
I want to add a property or function to the `Contact` class which returns the combination of two other fields (firstname and lastname).
The definition of the `IContact` interface looks like this:

```
export interface IContact {
    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;
}
```

The `Contact` class look like this:

```
export class Contact implements IContact {
    constructor(
        public firstname: string,
        public lastname: string
    ) { }

    public fullname(): string {
        return this.firstname + " " + this.lastname;
    }
}
```

In my view I want to output the result of `Contact.fullname()` but I receive an error that `fullname` is not a function.
I do have access to all other properties on that class.

==== UPDATE ===

I'll add some extra code to clarify some stuff.
When I output the `fullname` property in my view I have tried `contact.fullname()` but also `contact.fullname` which results in nothing.
In my component, trying to figure out what was happening I tried to output `fullname` to the console like this: `console.log("FULLNAME " +contact.fullname());`, but that give me the following message in the console: `EXCEPTION _this.contact.fullname is not a function`

===== UPDATED WITH ANSWER ========

As Sakuto stated correctly the list of contacts is created by some json received from the server. By creating a new instance entirely by calling it's constructor i was able to output the `fullname` property.
Thanks Sakuto!

Comment: `Contact.fullname()` .. are you calling _class.function()_? if so the function needs to be static..

Comment: No I'm calling the function on an instance of the `Contact` class.

Comment: Please, can you show your html?

Comment: The question is how you create your `Contact` object? See Sakuto's answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are probably trying to call this method on an object dynamically casted from a `JSON`. Dynamically `casted object` does not have the method defined in the class, they just respect the `contract` and have the property.

The only way to make your current code work is to create a new instance of `Contact` instead of just casting it with `<Contact> yourObject`;

The solution would be to do something like this:

```
let contactsList: Contact[] = [];
yourServiceReturn.ForEach(c => contactsList[] = new Contact(c.name, c.surname));
// You can now call getFullName on the object stored on contactsList
```

Comment: You are right that is the case and i understand the problem but not the solution.
Does it mean the the `Contact` class should not implement the `IContact` interface but have the same properties with a method `public fullname(): string`?
Could i then do the following:
`var contact = <Contact>contactItemFromCollection;`
`console.log(contact.fullname());`

Comment: No, the problem is that this kind of behavior is not implemented in the language, you can't cast an object to a class and get the method, you have to manually instantiate the object. Check my answer.

Comment: Ah yes! Thank you, that did it. I guess i was a bit too much in C#-mode.

Comment: @Sakuto - how did you know this? I didn't find any documentation regarding this gotcha for JSON-loaded TS classes..

Answer (score 0):

[How do I cast a JSON object to a typescript class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875636/how-do-i-cast-a-json-object-to-a-typescript-class)

```
onReceiveCompany( jsonCompany : any ) 
{
   let newCompany = new Company( jsonCompany );

   // call the methods on your newCompany object ...
}
```