# Learning TypeScript - Casting Types

Tags: typescript, inheritance, type-assertion

I'm new to TypeScript and I'm playing around with the various language features. Below is a code sample I've been working on during one of the many online courses.

I'm having issues getting inheritence and overloading to work properly.
throughout the code I make use of a car which is of base class Auto, and a truck which is off child class Truck.

I'm trying to see if it is possible to cast the car as a Truck and access the specialized function HonkHorn. 
Also I'm trying to cast a truck back to an Auto and access the base function for WriteDetails.

In both cases it seems the objects stay of their original type. So `typecast4.HonkHorn();` generates a runtime error:

> Uncaught TypeError: typecast4.HonkHorn is not a function.

Trying to cast back Truck to Auto will always result in the specialized override for WriteDetails to be called. The casting code is all the way at the bottom of the sample.

Can someone please help me understand why this is happening?

Thanks in advance!

```
// defines the structure of auto options
interface IAutoOptions{
    engine: Engine,
    color: string,
    price: number,
    year: number
}

// extends autooptions with truck specific options
interface ITruckOptions extends IAutoOptions{
    fourbyfour: boolean,
    bedlength: string
}

// defines the structure of engines
interface IEngine {
    enginetype: string;
    horsepower: number;
    hydraulicpump?: string
    start(warmuptime: number, callback: () => void): void;
    stop(): void;
}

// the engine class must implement the members as specified in the IEngine interface
class Engine implements IEngine{
    enginetype: string;
    horsepower: number;
    hydraulicpump?: string; //optional hydraulic parameter
    constructor(enginetype: string, horsepower: number, hydraulicpump? : string ) {
        this.enginetype = enginetype;
        this.horsepower = horsepower;
        if (!(hydraulicpump)){
            hydraulicpump = "Not Available"; //if no hydraulic parameter is provided we set it to "Not Available"
        }
        this.hydraulicpump = hydraulicpump;
    }
    // start requires a callback parameter which accepts a specialized callback object/function that accepts and returns nothing
    // by accepting a callback object/function that code can be seperated off, which makes this class much cleaner and organized
    start(warmuptime: number, callback: () => void) { 
        window.setTimeout(() => {
            callback();
            document.write(this.enginetype + " has started!" + "</br>");
        }, warmuptime);
    };
    stop() { 
        document.write(this.enginetype + " has stopped!" + "</br>");
    };
}

// base class for autos
class Auto {
    engine: Engine;
    color: string;
    price: number;
    year: number;

    constructor(options: IAutoOptions) {
        this.engine = options.engine;
        this.color = options.color;
        this.price = options.price;
        this.year = options.year;
    }

    //WriteDetails contains the base details for each Auto which can be overriden in specialized classes
    WriteDetails() {
        document.write("Color: " + this.color + "</br>");
        document.write("Year: " + this.year + "</br>");
        document.write("Price: $"  + this.price + "</br>");
        document.write("Engine Type: " + this.engine.enginetype + "</br>");
        document.write("Horse Power: " + this.engine.horsepower + "</br>");
        document.write("Hydraulic Pump: " + this.engine.hydraulicpump + "</br>");    
    };
}

// Truck extends Auto to add Truck specific fields and function overloads
// Note that it does not contains all the base fields from Auto thus making it much smaller and cleaner
// Only truck specific code is added.
class Truck extends Auto{
    fourbyfour: boolean;
    bedlength: string;
    constructor(options: ITruckOptions) {
        // to overload the constructor super() must to be called, which calls the base class constructor in Auto
        super(options);
        this.bedlength = options.bedlength;
        this.fourbyfour = options.fourbyfour;
    }
    // WriteDetails overrides the Auto WriteDetails, but first calls the base WriteDetails function
    WriteDetails() {
        super.WriteDetails();
        document.write("Bed Length: " + this.bedlength + "</br>");
        document.write("4x4 : " + this.fourbyfour + "</br>");
    };

    HonkHorn() {
        document.write("Honk Honk!</br>");
    }
}

// below is one of the notations to define a callback object that can be used to call
// the start function on the Engine class
// this callback function has encapsulated car specific logic for starting the engine
// much cleaner than putting the specialized code in the Auto class

var CarEngineStart = () => {
    document.write("<h1>Starting Car</h1>");
    document.write("Check Tires!" + "</br>");
    document.write("Fasten Seatbelts!" + "</br>");
    document.write("Check Mirrors!" + "</br>");
    document.write("Starting Engine!" + "</br>");
};

// yet another way to define a callback object (function)
// this callback function has encapsulated truck specific logic for starting the engine
// much cleaner than putting the specialized code in the Auto or Truck classes

function TruckEngineStart() {
    document.write("<h1>Starting Truck</h1>");
    document.write("Check Tires!" + "</br>");
    document.write("Check if load is properly fastened!" + "</br>");
    document.write("Check timesheet!" + "</br>");
    document.write("Fasten Seatbelts!" + "</br>");
    document.write("Check Mirrors!" + "</br>");
    document.write("Starting Engine!" + "</br>");
}

// ###################### Start logic

// creating an engine
var carengine = new Engine("V8", 300);
// creating another engine, but now providing the optional hydraulicpump parameter
var truckengine = new Engine("V12", 1000, "Flexpump 3000");

var car = new Auto({
    engine: carengine,
    color: 'Blue',
    price: 20000,
    year: 2017
});

var truck = new Truck({
    engine: truckengine,
    color: 'Red',
    price: 80000,
    year: 2015,
    bedlength: 'Long Bed',
    fourbyfour: true
});
document.write("<h1>Car Details</h1>");
car.WriteDetails();

document.write("<h1>Truck Details</h1>");
truck.WriteDetails();

truck.engine.start(10000, TruckEngineStart);
car.engine.start(5000, CarEngineStart);

window.setTimeout(() => {
    document.write("<h1>Stopping Car</h1>");
    car.engine.stop();
    document.write("<h1>Stopping Truck</h1>");
    truck.engine.stop();
}, 15000);

document.write("<h1>Casting Autos</h1>");
document.write("<h2>Auto WriteDetails for Car</h2>");
var typecast: Auto;
typecast = car;
typecast.WriteDetails();
document.write("<h2>Truck WriteDetails for Car with type cast</h2>");
var typecast4: Truck;
typecast4 = <Truck>car;
typecast4.HonkHorn();
typecast4.WriteDetails();
document.write("<h2>Auto WriteDetails for Truck without type cast</h2>");
var typecast2: Auto;
typecast2 = truck;
typecast2.WriteDetails();
document.write("<h2>Auto WriteDetails for Truck with type cast</h2>");
var typecast3: Auto;
typecast3 = <Auto>truck;
typecast3.WriteDetails();
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is no type casting in Typescript, but only type assertions. This is for type checking and it won't influence runtime behavior.

For example, the type assertion:

```
car as Truck  // older syntax syntax: <Truck> car
```

tells the compiler that the `car` is of type `Truck`, but it won't influence the generated JS code.

> TypeScript allows you to override its inferred and analyzed view of types in any way you want to. This is done by a mechanism called "type assertion". TypeScript's type assertion is purely you telling the compiler that you know about the types better than it does, and that it should not second guess you.
>
> Type Assertion vs. Casting
>
> The reason why it's not called "type casting" is that casting generally implies some sort of runtime support. However type assertions are purely a compile time construct and a way for you to provide hints to the compiler on how you want your code to be analyzed.

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-assertion.html

Update:

Another good reference nowadays is the [Typescript site itself](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions)

> Type assertions are a way to tell the compiler “trust me, I know what I’m doing.” A type assertion is like a type cast in other languages, but performs no special checking or restructuring of data. It has no runtime impact, and is used purely by the compiler. TypeScript assumes that you, the programmer, have performed any special checks that you need.

For changing the type, these answers here could be useful: [How do I cast a JSON Object to a TypeScript class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875636/how-do-i-cast-a-json-object-to-a-typescript-class)

Comment: @Školstvo Create a new instance or change the prototype.

Comment: Can this be done without changing the base class? I can't change the source I'm working with. That is why I opted to use an extension class.