# how to force typecasting in typescript DTO

Tags: typescript, types, casting

I'm trying to get forced typecasting working in typescript. I remember in the past i did something like the below example but it doesn't seem to work and im not sure if its because of the version of typescript or what etc. In the below example how could I force typecast the below example:

```
class UserDto {
    name: string;
    email: string;
    id: () => number; // before this used to work
}

let req = {
    name: 'John Doe',
    email: 'email@email.com',
    id: '10',
};

let res: UserDto  = req;

console.log(res);
```

Error:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '() => number'.
```

------------------ UPDATE - Making the goal a little clearer -------------

Lets say I have a post request that comes through like so:

```
{
    "userId": "10",
    "name": "John",
    "address": {
         "line1": "some road"
     }
}
```

and the DTO looks like this:

```
(interface | class) AddressDTO {
     line1: string;
}

(interface | class) UserDTO {
     userId: number;
     name: string;
     address: AddressDTO;
}
```

And then when we intercept the request and pass the data across to another part of the system so we do something like this. (This is what I DEFINITELY got working before but cant find the sources as it took me a long time to get it working. I though it was the 'id: "() =>" number' part which forced the casting to number)

Desired result:

```
let req = {
   "userId": "10",
   "name": "John",
   "address": {
       "line1": "some road"
    } 
};

let postData: UserDTO = req;

// output is as follow:
{
   "userId": 10, // here it's force cast to number
   "name": "John",
   "address": AddressDTO (set to: "line1": "some road")
};
```

Comment: Are you looking for `let res = req as unknown as UserDto;` ?

Comment: i tried both variants. I get the same error

Comment: Why do you want to make the id a string, but in the class it is a function?

Comment: no im trying to make a DTO where i just assign the let dto = <DTO> request.params;. Or something like that. but the issue im having is when url params are send through then it complains that i cant set the id to number as the param is a string. the only reason i have it as () => number is that is the only way i got it to force typecast the string id to a number in the past. As far as i remember it was a "class" that i used but it could be an interface etc i don't really know.

Answer (score 0):

You get a compile error as `'10'` is a string, and not a function that returns a number ( `() => number`)

You could fix that by *also* allowing a string, e g.

```
class UserDto {
    name: string;
    email: string;
    string | id: () => number; // allow both
}
```

But not sure if that's where you looking for. Casting the anonymous type to a class (e.g. UserDto) is a bit more tricky, see [How do I cast a JSON Object to a TypeScript class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875636/how-do-i-cast-a-json-object-to-a-typescript-class)

Please also note that `as` (or the old `<AnotherType>` syntax) isn't a cast.  It's a type assertion and basically says, "compiler I know the type better than you.". See [Learning TypeScript - Casting Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44967356/learning-typescript-casting-types)

Comment: Hi there. 
Thanks for the help. I'll update my question to make it a bit clearer. 
I actually already had this working in another example and unfortunately its been permanently deleted and cant figure out how to do it again.

Comment: I think you answer is still in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875636/how-do-i-cast-a-json-object-to-a-typescript-class

Comment: OK Thanks. There is definitely some answers in there that look like they could work. I'll work on it and get back to you.

Comment: I've had to put this down for the moment as im quite busy getting other elements of the project done. But i will have to come up with a solution soon. So i'll update my question when i have something working.