# Typescript dependent property

Tags: typescript

Coming from a C# background, I'd thought this should work in typescript. I have a class which contains a read-only property that depends on other two properties in the class.

```
export class Foo {
   bar1: number;
   bar2: number;
   get bar3(): boolean {
      return this.bar1 > this.bar2;
   }
}
```

Now in Angular 4 I have a service returning Observable e.g.

```
getFoos(fooId: number): Observable<Foo[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.url)
            .map((res: Response) => res.json());
    }
```

Note that my REST api response does NOT return `bar3` but only `bar1` and `bar2`.
Then in my component, when trying to access `Foo[]`, its entry doesn't have `bar3` property on it, only `bar1` and `bar2`.
So how to make `bar3` populated?

Comment: You have to create Foo object with new keyword otherwise all methods will not exist

Comment: An array of objects, parsed from JSON, is not automatically converted into an array of `Foo` objects just because they have two of three properties in common with `Foo`

Comment: @Andreas @MistyK sounds like you two are saying the same/similar thing; so how does `res.json()` convert to a strongly typed `Observable<Foo[]>` then? Does it call `new Foo()` at all?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I cast a JSON object to a typescript class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875636/how-do-i-cast-a-json-object-to-a-typescript-class)

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment `res.json()` gives you type `any` so there is no check at all. Normally typescript use [duck typing](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) to check if your object properties match interface properties.
To solve your problem you should either create your object something along these lines:

```
  getFoos(fooId: number): Observable<Foo[]> {
            return this.http.get(this.url)
                .map((res: Response) => res.json().then(data)=>{
                    return data.map(el=>{
                      let obj = new Foo();
                      return {obj, ...el};
                      }
});
        }
```

Or follow some suggestions described here:
[How do I cast a JSON object to a typescript class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875636/how-do-i-cast-a-json-object-to-a-typescript-class)