# create object structure of type from JSON.parse object

Tags: json, typescript, type-conversion

I am getting a JSON object with a JSON.parse function. I am facing the problem of converting the object to `Data` object. This is how `Data` is declared (it is simplified and the methods are omitted):

```
export class Data {
    private static _instance: AppData;
    private projects?: Project[] = Array();
    constructor() {
    }

    public static get Instance() {
       //create singleton
    }
}
export class Project {
    projectID: string;
    projectNumber: number;
    projectName: string;
    dateCreated: number;
    thumbnail: string;
    details?: Detail[] = [];


}
export class Detail {
    detailID:string;
    detailName: string;
    detailNumber:number;
    dateCreated:number;
    textElements?: Text[];

}


export class Text {
    text: string;
    textSize: number;
    transform: Transform[];
    transiton: Transiton[];
}

export class Transiton{
    name:string;
}
export class Transform{
    name:string;
}
```

Silly me, tried to typecast the whole object with `as`. Then I tried to write constructors, but it got terribly complicated due to each `Data` object having an array of `Project` objects, each project having an array of Detail objects... each detail having an array of `Text`  objects and so on.

Is there a better way of doing this instead of just creating a ton of nested loops?

Comment: What's wrong with typecasting the whole object with `as`?

Comment: according to console.log, it doesn't work. For example, Projects[] is just an Array of objects and not array of Project objects.

Comment: TypeScript will always be compiled to JavaScript, and console.log will run after it has been compiled. It will never display any types.

Comment: it does display types. https://imgur.com/a/a0NGr . Those Projects were created with a constructor call. I also tried instanceof  method on a previously typecasted object and it is not of the type to which it should be typecasted with as.

Comment: Right, I get what you are saying now. Unfortunately, you cannot use TypeScript to actually change the underlying JS type of your object in a simple way. For an actual answer to your question, you can refer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875636/how-do-i-cast-a-json-object-to-a-typescript-class