# How to get object from api and map it to angular model?

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, angular5

I want to get the model from my api.

For this I use the method:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public MyModel GetModel()
    {
        MyModel model = new MyModel() { ... };

        return model;
    }
```

How can I get the model result in angular and how do I map `MyModel` to my angular model?

I have the following:

```
getModel() {
    var url = '/MyController/GetModel/';
    this.http.get(url)
        .map((data: Response) => {
            return data.json() as MyModel;
        })
        .toPromise().then(x => {
            this.myModel = x;
        })
}
```

which I call in `ngOnInit` of my component.

But I'm getting an error:

```
Uncaught (in promise): SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

What's wrong with my angular request?

Comment: please check if your response is a valid json - [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: which version of Angular you are using? if its 4.3+ and you are using HttpClient then you are using older approach in your code examples.

Comment: It's Angular 5 and I'm using `Http` @Sergey

Comment: this link should help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875636/how-do-i-cast-a-json-object-to-a-typescript-class

Comment: @Avinash I was returning the object not the json as per my code above. I changed the method to return json eg. `public JsonResult GetModel()
        {
            MyModel myModel = new MyModel() {..};

   var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myModel);

            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }` but now angular request doesn't even hit the action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working like this:

```
getModel() {
    var url = '/MyController/GetModel/';
    return this.http.get(url)
        .map((data: Response) => {
            return data.json();
        }).toPromise().then(x => {
            this.myModel = new MyModel(x);
        })
}
```

`MyModel` has to have a constructor accepting `json` string.

Answer (score 0):

the http.get takes a generic 
so you can do this.

```
  getModel() {
        var url = '/MyController/GetModel/';
        this.http.get<MyModel>(url).toPromise().then(x => {
                this.myModel = x;
        });
    }
```

unless the model in your angular is diferent from the model from the api

Comment: what if my angular model is not the same as the api model? @Obed

Comment: I can't even build it because of errors: `<MyModel>` says: `'Expected 0 arguments, but got 1'` and `x =>`: `'Parameter 'x' implicitly has an 'any' type'`. @Obed

Comment: check this link, https://nehalist.io/working-with-models-in-angular/ a cool way to go around it.
what where are you importing your http object from?

Comment: Thanks @Obed your suggestion helped me to write the right code.