# Angular httpClient map response to entity with behaviour

Tags: angular, typescript, httpclient

I'm trying to map the response of my GET-request to an entity-class.
When calling a function on that response-object an error is thrown:

> TypeError: res.foo is not a function

GET-Request:

```
 this.http.get<TodoEntity>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1').subscribe((res) => {
    console.log(res.foo());
  })
```

Entity-Class:

```
export class TodoEntity {
 public userId: number;
 public id: number;
 public title: string;
 public completed: boolean;
 public foo(): string {
    return 'Hello world';
 }
}
```

Is there a way to map the response directly to an entity class and call a function on it? Or do I have to manually create a new instance of **TodoEntity** based on the response-object?

I'm using typescript 3.1.6 with angular 7.3.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create an instance of the class. The methods are not available when you cast your JSON into prototypical JavaScript/ TypeScript class.

Edit:
Just found a good explanation here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22875957/894532

Answer (score 1):

You can use the RxJS' [`map`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html) operator to build a `TodoEntity` instance from the set of properties returned by the webservice, using [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1').pipe(
  map(res => Object.assign(new TodoEntity(), res))
).subscribe((res: TodoEntity) => {
  console.log(res.foo());
});
```

**Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-igaw2q**