# Express body request not match with model, but its still working?

Tags: node.js, typescript

My class model:

```
class User {
   userName: string;
   password: string;
}
```

My function handle:

```
const users = [];
function addUser(user: User) {
  users.push(user);
}
```

Express router:

```
router.post('/users', (req, res) => {
  addUser(req.body);
})
```

I want to request following userModel format.
But when I request an object not following userModel format, addUser function still working and push a wrong object format to users[].

How I can throw error if req.body not match with userModel

Comment: I'm not typescript master but shouldn't array also have type: `const users: User[] = [];`

Comment: You can also check this module: https://github.com/ooesili/type-safe-json-decoder

Comment: @baza92 Thanks for comment. But when I try to run function by ts-node, I get error when wrong format. But when I run server and request, it's not working. This issue is wrong property name it's still works. I think that module not handle the issue. Don't care to User[] because it's just visual DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to implement desired behaviour using [type-safe-json-decoder](http://github.com/ooesili/type-safe-json-decoder):

**index.js**

```js
import express = require("express");
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import { Decoder, object, string } from 'type-safe-json-decoder'

const app: express.Application = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

class User {
    constructor(userName: string, password: string) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password
    }
    userName: string;
    password: string;
}

const usersDecoder: Decoder<User> = object(
    ['userName', string()],
    ['password', string()],
    (userName, password) => ({ userName, password })
);

const users: User[] = [];
function addUser(user: User) {
    users.push(user);
    console.log(users);
}

app.post('/add', (req, res) => {
    const user: User = usersDecoder.decodeJSON(JSON.stringify(req.body))
    addUser(user);
    res.send("User added!");
});

app.listen(8080, () => console.log("Listening on 8080"));
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "ts",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "tsc": "tsc"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.16.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "type-safe-json-decoder": "^0.2.0",
    "typescript": "^3.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/body-parser": "^1.17.0"
  }
}
```

In order **to run**:

1. `npm install`
2. `npm run tsc -- --init`
3. `npm run tsc`
4. `node index.js`

When executing POST with proper JSON you should receive: `User added!`.

In case of incorrect JSON format an **error** should be thrown:
[image: error example]

Comment: I don't know why type-safe-json-decoder installed but when I import it's I see Cannot find module :/

Comment: But, the model have many properties. I also user Decoder to validate :/

Comment: @VũAnhDũng I'm not fully understand. Can you share your code which is not working? "Cannot find module" indicates that you didn't install the module.

Comment: I have been installed the module. I mean I will have to use Decoder for all apis, all attributes of models.

Comment: If you want to parse json to object in more automatic way there are some alternatives available - you can check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875636/how-do-i-cast-a-json-object-to-a-typescript-class