# Why am I getting ERROR TypeError: "xyz" is not a function?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the following code:

MatchComponent

```
import { AllData } from './../../data-handling/all.data';
import { MatchService } from '../../data-handling/match.service';
import { Component, OnInit, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { Match } from '../../data-handling/match';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-match',
  templateUrl: './match.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./match.component.css']
})
export class MatchComponent implements OnInit {

  match: Match;

  constructor(private matchService: MatchService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  // ...
  loadMatch(): void {
    console.log(AllData.allMatches);
    this.match = AllData.allMatches[0];
    console.log(this.match);
  }

  getGame(match: Match): string {
    console.log('getGame');
    console.log(match); // prints the expected output (match object exists)
    match.getGameFromAll();
    return 'test';
  }
  // ...
}
```

Match

```
export class Match {
    // ...

    public getGameFromAll(): void {
        console.log('XXXXXXXXXXX');
    }

    // ...
}
```

AllData:

```
import { Match } from './match';

export class AllData {
    static allMatches: Match[];
}
```

And the html template:

```
<button (click)="loadMatch()">Load Match</button>
<!-- ... -->
<div *ngIf="match">
    <h4> {{getGame(match)}} </h4>
</div>
<!-- ... -->
```

I am loading all Matches with http into the allMatches Array. That works. After that I press the Button "Load Match" which triggers the action, that a single Match is loaded into the MatchComponent. Judging by the console outputs that also works.

When the match object exists, the getGame function is called in the MatchComponent. From my understanding, there actually should occur the text "test" on the website after running the code. But after printing "getGame" in the console it says, the following:

```
ERROR TypeError: match.getGameFromAll is not a function
```

Most probably this is a simple issue but to be honest I am not getting behind it why I cannot call getGameFromAll?

Comment: can you be more specific about `AllData` I don't see it imported into your code also I can't see  where it is populated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry I missed to copy paste it, i edited my question. `AllData` is imported in the MatchComponent

Comment: yes thank you but still where is `AllData` getting the data?

Comment: I checked already with logs, that the allMatches array is correctly populated. I don't think that the issue is there. Therefore I didnt post the http part.

Comment: The problem might be that the data is loaded asynchronously by http and you access it before it's loaded

Comment: i think the method - getGameFromAll should be in a service not in the Match clss

Comment: The website loads all the files into the allMatches array, when it is initialized. After some while i press the "load match" button. Therefore i avoid the asynchronous problem. Not a nice way, I know, but its a prototype. With the ngIf in the html i guarantee that there is a match object available

Comment: @user3255080 when you console.log(this.match); do you see a getGameFromAll() function inside of it?

Comment: no, somehow not, why can this be?

Comment: please provide a [mcve], with emphasis on **minimal complete** code, there are essential parts missing. You can test how much code is needed to reproduce the issue by creating a stackblitz for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem seems simple enough. You are getting json objects from your http call that are not prototype objects and thus don't have the methods implemented in them.

The JSON object does have the same members in terms of variable names but they don't have the constructor, methods etc.

If you are using observables, then you are going to need to cast the JSON object to Prototype object and return the result at the place where you subscribe into the http GET request.

You can take a look at this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875636/how-do-i-cast-a-json-object-to-a-typescript-class)