# Converting a JSON object into specific type

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, interface

I have a JSON object which contains a bunch of strings...

```
{
    id: "1",
    amount: "57,000",
    title: "I am a test"
}
```

How can I convert this into an interface such as:

```
interface MyObj {
   id: number;
   amount: number;
   title: string;
}
```

Would I need to map over each object property and try to convert to the necessary type or can I simply try and force cast a JSON object into a type?

For clarity, here is some additional information.

I have an array of the example objects above, the JSON so...

```
[
{
    id: "1",
    amount: "57,000",
    title: "I am a test"
},
{
    id: "2",
    amount: "2347,000",
    title: "I am a test as well"
}
]
```

All the values within this JSON object are string. Each time we use the objects in TS, we want their types to be correct. For example, the id and amount should be numbers, they can be converted before they are stored in our state.

So I would like to convert the JSON objects in the array above into a specific interface or type. Because the types do not match I cannot just use the interface, I need to do some conversions or try and cast to a type before actually aligning to the interface. This is the question, how can I map over the JSON objects in the array and convert some of the keys from string to number (possibly?).

Comment: Casting won't work as expected since `amount` and `id` are actually of type `string`, or is that a mistake in your example?

Comment: What do you mean? When are you trying to process these - before compile-time (generating TS source), at compile-time, after compile-time/at run-time?

Comment: The types are intentionally mismatched. That is partly the issue. How would I convert the JSON object with all string values, into a respectable interface. I.e. try and cast id and number to number or default it potentionally.

Comment: Is the comma in `57,000` supposed to be a *decimal separator* or a *thousand separator*?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I cast a JSON Object to a TypeScript class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875636/how-do-i-cast-a-json-object-to-a-typescript-class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript is a development/build-time tool only; that means casting (like using `as`) doesn't have any effect at runtime, like converting strings to numbers. Casting or using `as` is just a way of telling TypeScript to explicitly consider a value as being of a particular type. If you tried this:

```
interface MyObj {
   id: number;
   amount: number;
   title: string;
}

const data = {
    id: "1",
    amount: "57,000",
    title: "I am a test"
};

const ofType = data as MyObj;
```

...TypeScript will not compile since `data` is not compatible with your interface given that the types don't align. Even if you forced it with:

```
const ofType = data as unknown as MyObj;
```

...`id` and `amount` are still going to be strings, and now you've forced a bug in your application.

TypeScript is there as a quality assurance tool for the soundness of your code; it brings nothing to the table for data conversion. So just like as with pure JavaScript, you'll have to do custom code if you need to convert things from one type to another. For example, if you have a parsed JSON array as posted:

```
const converted: Array<MyObj> = data.map(item => ({
  id: parseInt(item.id),
  amount: parseInt(item.replace(/,/g, '')),
  title: item.title
}));
```

Comment: Ok, so if I have an array of these JSON objects, I'd need to try and parseInt for each object within the array into its type.

Comment: Yep, you could use something like calling `map` on the array and doing the conversion inside of that function.

Comment: This seems to be most aligned to what the question is. I've added some more information for clarity too.

Answer (score 3):

**JSON.parse reviver**

[JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) can take an optional second argument, a `reviver` function -

> If a `reviver` is specified, the value computed by parsing is transformed before being returned. Specifically, the computed value and all its properties (beginning with the most nested properties and proceeding to the original value itself) are individually run through the `reviver`. Then it is called, with the object containing the property being processed as this, and with the property name as a string, and the property value as arguments. If the `reviver` function returns `undefined` (or returns no value, for example, if execution falls off the end of the function), the property is deleted from the object. Otherwise, the property is redefined to be the return value.

```js
function MyObject({ id, amount, title }) {
  this.id = id
  this.amount = amount
  this.title = title
}

function reviver(key, value) {
  if (value?.id && value?.amount && value?.title)
    return new MyObject(value)
  else
    return value
}

const json =
  `[{"id":"1","amount":"57,000","title":"I am a test"},{"id":"2","amount":"13,000","title":"I am also test"},{"id":"3","amount":"1,000","title":"I am a third test"},{"id":"4","amount":"200","something":"else"},1,"foo"]`

const data =
  JSON.parse(json, reviver)

for (const value of data)
  console.log(value)
```

```js
MyObject { id: '1', amount: '57,000', title: 'I am a test' }
MyObject { id: '2', amount: '13,000', title: 'I am also test' }
MyObject { id: '3', amount: '1,000', title: 'I am a third test' }
{ id: '4', amount: '200', something: 'else' }
1
foo
```

**do it better**

Above `revive` is a somewhat fragile function. Because of this, it would be recommended that your `JSON.stringify`'d data contains a `type` field, or similar -

```js
[ { type: "MyObject", ... }, { type: "Another", ... }, "foo", 1, ... ]
```

Now we can write `reviver` in a simple way -

```js
function reviver(key, value) {
  switch (value?.type) {
    case "MyObject": return MyObject(value)
    case "OtherThing": return OtherThing(value)
    case "Another": return Another(value)
    default: return value                   // revive without modification
  }
}
```

Comment: My reading of the question was that OP has the objects and wants to produce TS interfaces out of them. Although, the mention of "casting" suggests maybe they want to produce these objects (there is no casting in TS, just type assertion - essentially, lying to the compiler). If the intention is to *produce them*, then according to the interface, `id` and `amount` are numerics, rather than strings.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

What you all need is a `parseInt()` function.

Use it as follows:

```
const obj = {
    id: "1",
    amount: "57,000",
    title: "I am a test"
};

print(parseInt(obj.amount))         <-    Number and not string
```

If you want to confirm the type of variable, you can use `typeof` operator as follows:

```
print(typeof parseInt(obj.amount))
```

Comment: `parseInt("57,000")` produces `57` not `57000`

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**

I noticed that the given object is different from the `interface MyObj`

Therefore you can't do `type assertion`( can't use `as`). You must convert the given object to your type!

So what you need to do - if you know the given object looks like that:

```
const data: any = {
    id: "1",
    amount: "57,000",
    title: "I am a test"
}
```

You should do:

```
const myObj: MyObj = {
   id: parseInt(data['id']),
   amount: parseInt(data['amount'].replaceAll(',','')),
   title: data['title']
}
```

if you don't sure its look like the `data` consider to add more validation / default values

for example if data['id'] is undefined the Id will be NaN
and if the data['title'] is undefined maybe you should add default value

Comment: There is no casting in TypeScript. `as` just overrules the compiler - it's called a type assertion. ***YOU DO NOT GET ANY CONVERSION IN THE PROCESS!!!*** [runnable example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8DyAjAVsgbwFgAoZc4AEwC5kQBXAW22gG5Tzk5GB7e8Wg2ZsO5MMDAAbCLQDOYKKADm7EgF9SpBDxDzklOGDjU4IdMgC8hURRrIARAEZ7AGhtde-MLXsBWAOwuAAwhru7iUjIOAJIeXMiQ8vakaqpaOno8eLQYOPhWBkZcsmhYeGkk2ro80gB0kjxKABRZuLVUyADUyABMAJSsyAD0Q4496dV1Dc2t7ZS1YDwAYsAAHhCUTf0Dw0PQUDxQQA)

Comment: Yes you right! I used Incorrect terminology

Comment: The bolded and italicised part is more important. Using `as` doesn't change anything about the data.

Comment: Yep you right again! I didn't noticed the interface is different from the interface.. i changed the post :)

Answer (score 0):

First declare a `class` in which you want to convert JSON:

```
class LoginResponse {
  constructor(obj) {
    Object.assign(this, obj);
  }
  access_token;
  token_type;
  expires_in;
}
```

Now Convert your JSON to a javascript general object:

```
  const jsonString = '{"access_token": "123abc", "token_type": "Bearer", "expires_in": "24"}';
  var javascriptsObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

Now convert the general javascript object into your desired class object:

```
  let desiredObject = new LoginResponse(javascriptsObject);
  console.log(desiredObject);
```

Output will be:

```
 LOG  {"access_token": "123abc", "expires_in": "24", "token_type": "Bearer"}
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple cast will do.

Look here

```js
var test = {
  name: ""
};

// umnown type will be 

console.log(test.name) // this is simple like test["name"].

// Now if you want it to a specific type then

interface Itest {
  name: string;
}

var myobj = test as Itest;
// or 

var myobj = < Itest > test;

// then the property will be a known property

console.log(myobj.name);
```

Comment: 1, There is no casting in TypeScript. 2. It's called "type assertion" 3. It works by *lying to the compiler* about what type you have, it doesn't actually *convert* anything (again - no casting).

Comment: friend read this https://acdcjunior.dev/typescript-cast-object-to-other-type-or-instanceof.html

Comment: The article is wrong. There is no casting - run this example [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8DyAjAVsgbwFgAoZc4AEwC5kQBXAW22gG5Tzk5GB7e8Wg2ZsO5MMDAAbCLQDOYKKADm7EgF9SpBDxDzklOGDjU4IdMgC8hURRrIARAEZ7AGhtde-MLXsBWAOwuAAwhru7iUjIOAJIeXMiQ8vakaqpaOno8eLQYOPhWBkZcsmhYeGkk2ro80gB0kjxKABRZuLVUyADUyABMAJSsyAD0Q4496dV1Dc2t7ZS1YDwAYsAAHhCUTf0Dw0PQUDxQQA) - the code compiles but no conversion is made. There is a runtime error because `id` is not actually a number.

Comment: Yes there is no error. If you read my example this is only so the property will be a known property, with type and name. I never said converting. read my example and you will see that I wrote known and unknown. Note you will need to write this example on visual studio so you will understand

Comment: "*I never said converting*" -> casting means converting. TS does no casting because there is no conversion. And suggesting a type assertion *with mismatched types* is just a recipe for a very hard to find bugs in the code. You've already overruled the compiler, so you don't get the normal compile-time errors. Only runtime ones that might not even show immediately. There are *extremely* few cases where type assertion is appropriate. In all of them, you have to be *extremely* careful. This is neither careful, nor is an appropriate use of type assertion.

Answer (score -2):

I think what you are trying to do is turn the JSON object into a JavaScript object by parsing the JSON object.

An example of how you could do this is below:

```
const json = '{"result": true, "count": 42}';
const obj = JSON.parse(json);
```

You could then access the new JavaScript object, obj, just like a regular object. It will contain the exact same information that was in the json object.

For more information about this method, visit:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp