# Angular 2 http service

Tags: json, angular

I'm learning Ang2. I ran the Hero tutorial successfully. to practice, I just added a link in the main page to a get a new component. there is a json file with a list of Radio Station. the following are my service, and the Component:

```
    import { Radio } from '../models/radio';

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export /**
 * RadioService
 */
    class RadioService {
    radios: Radio[] = [];
    len: Number = 0;
    http: Http;
    constructor(http: Http) {
        this.http = http;
    }
    getRadios() {
        console.log('Radios Service is being called');
        this.http.get('app/mock/FranceRadioJSON.json')
            .map((res: Response) => res.json())
            .subscribe((rad: Radio[]) => {      // Succes
                console.log('Radios Service Success');
                this.radios = rad;
                this.len = rad.length;
            }

            , err => {// Failure
                console.log('Radio Services Failure');
                console.error(err);
            }

            , // complete
            () => {
                console.log('Get Radios Complete');
                console.log('Records NB: ' + this.len);
                console.log('radios nb: ' + this.radios.length)
            }
            )
            ;
        return this.radios;

    }
```

and the Component is:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RouteParams } from '@angular/router-deprecated';
import { Radio } from '../../models/radio';
import { RadioService } from '../../services/radio.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'radio'
    , templateUrl: 'app/html/radio.component.html'
    , providers: [RadioService]
})
export /**
 * RadioComponent
 */
    class RadioComponent {
    radios: Radio[] = [];
    constructor(
        private radioservice: RadioService) {
    }
    getRadios() {
        this.radios = this.radioservice.getRadios();
        console.log('radio component NB: ' + this.radios.length);
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.getRadios()


    }
}
```

the problem is the call of service is coming first, and no Radio is return while when the service is called with console.log I see that's is successful and get all records from JSON file. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't get data this way from async calls (which is when you use `Promise` or `Observable`). `Http` returns and `Observable`. You need to `subscribe()` and in the callback you pass to `subscribe(...)` you get the data and can assign it to local properties.

And example how you can solve this:

In `getRadios` we don't call `subscribe()` and use `map()` instead. `map()` returns an `Observable` which allows the caller to get the data. `subscribe()` returns a `Subscription` and **doesn't** allow to get the response data, it only allows to cancel the subscription (which is also often handy, but not now ;-) ).

```
getRadios() {
    console.log('Radios Service is being called');
    return this.http.get('app/mock/FranceRadioJSON.json')
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .map((rad: Radio[]) => {      // Succes
            console.log('Radios Service Success');
            this.radios = rad;
            this.len = rad.length;
        });
}
```

We subscribe in `getRadios` because here we want to get the data. When we subscribe, the `map()` calls in `getRadios` are executed as well. `subscribe()` makes the `Observable` actually do its work:

```
getRadios() {
    this.radios = this.radioservice.getRadios()
        .subscribe((radios) => {
           this.radios = radios;
        } , err => {// Failure
            console.log('Radio Services Failure');
            console.error(err);
        } , // complete
        () => {
            console.log('Get Radios Complete');
            console.log('Records NB: ' + this.len);
            console.log('radios nb: ' + this.radios.length)
        });

    // executed before the HTTP get call to the server
    // console.log('radio component NB: ' + this.radios.length);
}
```

Because data is not returned immediately but only when the callback passed to `subscribe(...)` is executed you can get errors for bindings like

```
<div>{{radios.xxx}}</div>
```

when `radios` is still `null` when Angular2 already resolves the bindings in the template. To avoid errors you can use the safe-navigation (Elvis) operator

```
<div>{{radios?.xxx}}</div>
```

Angular2 doesn't try to access `.xxx` while `radios` is `null`.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. I do see much better the process.

Comment: How can I force the service to return Radio[], or should I convert the response in Component?

Comment: You didn't provide the `Radio` class (or interface) and also not how the data looks like you get from the observable. Hard to tell without full information.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22885995/how-do-i-initialize-a-typescript-object-with-a-json-object might be what you are looking for.

Comment: let's say the Radio Class is:
export class Radio {
    location: string;
     type: string;
}
and the jason files is a [] of this class

Comment: instead of `.map((res: Response) => res.json())` do `.map((res: Response) => { result = res.json(); return result.map(r => new Radio(r.location, r.type);})` and in the `Radio` class add `constructor(private location, private type) {}` (you need to remove the `location` and `type` properties from the class because with `private xxx` in the constructor argument list they are already declared as class properties.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are subscribing to your observable from within your service. Your service should return an *[**Observable**](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/observable.md)* and then you *[**Subscribe**](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/subscribe.md)* to it from your component.

So your service should be:

```
getRadios() : Observable<Radio[]> {
    return this.http.get('app/mock/FranceRadioJSON.json')
                    .map((res: Response) => <Radio[]>res.json())
}
```

And your component:

```
getRadios() {
    this.radios = this.radioservice.getRadios().subscribe(
        r => {
             this.radios = r;   
        }
        ...
    );
}
```

Comment: Which module must be imported in order to include Observable? I'm getting Cannot find Name 'Observable'

Comment: `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';`