# Angular2 JSON Objects

Tags: javascript, json, rest, angular

I have an application with RESTful services. I get a JSON object from a server but I don't know the keys inside of this object. Is it restricted to define a class for JSON objects with specific keys? How can I store the JSON object that I got from the server?

Comment: If you get it from the server and assign it to a variable it is already stored. Actually I don't really understand your question. Can you please add some code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish?

Comment: When I define a variable as public data: json; and assign the object that I get from the server to this variable, data is being undefined. I meant isn't there a json type in Angular2?

Comment: No, typescript has type . Angular has no type

Comment: Bunyamin , how are you planning to work with not known properties ? If I'm wrong correct me you meant object attributes/properties by `keys` ? 
Use Json.et for .net  and Jackson for java to map your json to objects.

Comment: One question sounds like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22885995/how-do-i-initialize-a-typescript-object-with-a-json-object. The other seems to be that you are accessing the value where it doesn't yet have a value but that's hard to tell without seeing your code.

Comment: @DavutGürbüz I need specific keys and I will check them if they exists.

Comment: If you are owner of server side as well. You can return `"class:com.project.Person"` to define Json object type and map accordingly.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer oh, you are right. I made a rookie mistake and check the data with console.log(). When I gave it to the view, it comes asynchronously. Thanks.

Comment: @DavutGürbüz I am not the owner of the server, just implementing the front-end. I don't use java or .net. I'm working with Angular2.

Comment: So as discussed angular is not typesafe, think about if you need a typed object and implement your front-end accordingly. But if you were owener of  your backend you would create a wrapper object for your response and put object metadata with reflection in it aside data. Anyways. Good luck on your problem.

Comment: @DavutGürbüz This is what is meant by `key` and `value`in a JSON object: `{key: value}`

Comment: @BünyaminSarıgül Do you mean something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/684692/6774296 Looping through the JSON object to get all `key`s, even those, which are unknown to you?

Comment: @RicoBrassers Yes, It's clear now. I couldn't comprehend at first glance because question was asking about defining a class on Json... I mapped it to Json to java/.net Object  problem but it appeared as frontend only. It is still unclear to me what is trying to achieve with this. There is a service returning different type of objects and we will build its screen ??? If you can elaborate more...

Comment: @DavutGürbüz I think, it's the following problem:  There is a (independent) service returning JSON Objects and he builds a frontend for that, but he doesn't have access to the server (code) directly.

Comment: @RicoBrassers Yes, you are right. I solved the problem and it was a simple mistake actually. Thank you all for your attention.

Comment: @BünyaminSarıgül You might want to write a answer to your question and mark the question as solved. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to assign the object out of the asynchronous function, so it was undefined since the function not responded yet. I thought its reason was that we cannot assign JSON object without creating a class with specified attributes, but I was totally wrong. I assigned the object to a variable inside of the async function and now I can access all attributes in it.

Answer (score 0):

> I get a JSON object from a server but I don't know the keys inside of
>   this object.

Using RESTful serivce, you should know what the structure of data is. You can check what data you get with some tools like Postman(Chrome) or SOAP UI. That kind of service is a more *loose* idea than communication between for exampletwo Java applications using serialization (when you have two strictly typed classes).
You **can** do something like this:

```
var d = new MyRichObject();
d.copyInto(jsonResult);
```

([How do I cast a JSON object to a typescript class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875636/how-do-i-cast-a-json-object-to-a-typescript-class))

> I don't know the keys inside of
>   this object

You **can** check the object for keys.

> if ('key' in myObj)

so you can determinate what data you get from service.

Comment: The server doesn't give me the same structure every time. There may be additional keys for different queries.

Comment: You can either standardize REST service or check for having specific keys in response.

Comment: @BünyaminSarıgül, if you're writing a class to describe an object with a known structure, but some fields can be absent, and make those fields optional.

Comment: Standardized REST structure is the BEST path you can choose.

Comment: @JacobM I think the problem here is, that he does not have access to the server code directly, because it's a third party service. So he can't use standardized REST structures, if they are not implemented serverside or not/poorly documented.

Comment: Yup. Realized that after his comments above. The only way now is to check object keys and parse json to corresponding class.