# Angular2. Map http response to concrete object instance

Tags: json, angular, rxjs, angular-http

Сommon approach to process http response is like that:

```
return this._http.get(url)
           .map((res: Response) => res.json());
```

which provides you with an `Observable<Object[]>` where `Object` is dynamically created type from json de-serialization.
Then you can use this result in `*ngFor="let item of result | async"` etc...

I'd like to get a specific type instance (meaning using `new` operator to call the type's constructor).
Tried different ways to achieve something like that:

```
.map((res: Response) => { let obj = res.json(); return new MyObject(obj.id, obj.name);})
```

but getting this error: `Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.`

This way seems to work but it's way too complicated and probably not effective:

```
.map((res: Response) => {
    let results = <MyObject[]>[];
    let obj = res.json();
    obj.forEach(
        function (o: any) {
            results.push(new MyObject(o.id, o.name));
        }
    );
    return results;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try `Observable<Array<Object>>`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22885995/how-do-i-initialize-a-typescript-object-with-a-json-object/22886730#22886730

Comment: `*ngFor` only supports arrays, not objects

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534959/access-key-and-value-of-object-using-ngfor

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I need to find a time to go through these posts. I hoped there's something built into Observable too achieve that. I updated my question with the the way which seems to work but I don't like it.

Answer (score 2):

If you know what type of objects you want to deconstruct from the JSON (which you probably do) you can create a static method that returns an instance from Object.

```
class MyClass {

  prop: number;

  static fromObject(src: Object) {
    var obj = new MyClass();
    obj.prop = src.prop;
    return obj;
  }
}
```

Then convert the JSON response to instances of `MyClass`:

```
Rx.Observable.of('[{"prop":1},{"prop":2},{"prop":3}]')
  .map(val => JSON.parse(val))
  .exhaustMap(val => new Rx.Observable.from(val))
  .map(val => MyClass.fromObject(val))
  .subscribe(
    item => console.log('Next: ', item),
    error => console.log('Error:', error),
    _ => console.log('Completed')
  );
```

How this works:

1. `.map(val => JSON.parse(val))` Just converts the response to JSON which is an array of objects.
2. `.exhaustMap(val => new Rx.Observable.from(val))` Converts each value to an Observable and `exhaustMap` flattens them so each object from the JSON will be emitted separately.
3. `.map(val => MyClass.fromObject(val))` Use `map` again to convert each Object to an instance of `MyClass`.

See live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/f5k9zdh1/1/

Comment: Interesting. Still too much code to my taste ;) but I'll take a deeper look. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
.map((res: Response) => res.json().map(obj => new MyObject(obj.id, obj.name)))
```

Comment: Code-only answer are not helpful. Please attempt to explain how your code solves OP's problem. Others who find this question through search may not be as experienced as you; help them understand your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax, you cast it to your object:

```
 this.http.post(this.constants.taskUrl + parm, { headers: headers })
            .map((response: Response) => {
                var res = response.json();
                var result = <DataResponseObject>response.json();
                return result;
            })
```

Comment: The deal here is that `response.json()` gives you an array of objects. I updated my question with the way that seems to work but I don't like that way.