# Deserialize JSON Object with arrays in Typescript

Tags: json, typescript, deserialization

I want to deserialize a `JSON` Object in `Typescript`. I have found this relevant [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22885995/how-do-i-initialize-a-typescript-object-with-a-json-object) I would like to use the `approach 4` of the accepted answer. However I am not sure if this would work in my case, since the object has member of `arrays` of other objects and so do the objects in the `array` as well. Moreover I would like to use a generic method/approach which deserializes the objects even if one does not know where the object dependencies end. The object structure looks like:

```
class Parent {

s: string;
x: number;
children : Array<Child1>
...

} 

class Child1 {

t: string;
y: number;
children : Array<Child2>
...

}

class Child2 {

k: string;
z: number;
children : Array<Child3>;
...

}

...
```

How can I deserialize these type of objects? I would be satisfied even with an approach which takes the end of the object structure for granted.

Comment: That link doesn't work

Comment: Can you add an example of the json you want to deserialize?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand your full requirements, but the method that you say you want to use basically makes each class responsible for deserializing itself. So if parent knows it has a `Child1` array, it knows it can iterate over the `children` array in the json and then call on `Child1` to deserialize each child. `Child1` can then do the same for its children, and so on:

```
class Parent {
    s: string;
    x:number;
    children: Child1[] = [];

    deserialize(input) {
        this.s = input.s;
        this.x = input.x;
        for(let child of input.children){
            this.children.push(new Child1().deserialize(child))
        }
        return this;
    }
}

class Child1{
    t: string;
    y: number;
    children: Child2[] = []
    deserialize(input) {
        this.t = input.t;
        this.y = input.x;
        for(let child of input.children){
            this.children.push(new Child2().deserialize(child))
        }

        return this;
    }
}

class Child2{
    deserialize(input) {
        //...
        return this;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid having to list out all the properties, I used this [link](https://nehalist.io/working-with-models-in-angular/).

The premise is to have a deserializable interface which the classes implement:

```
export interface Deserializable {
   deserialize(input: any): this;
}
```

We then make use of Object.assign.

Classes:

```
class Parent {
    s: string;
    x: number;
    children: Child1[] = [];

    deserialize(input) {
        Object.assign(this, input);
        let deserializedChildren: Child1[] = [];
        for(let child of input.children){
            deserializedChildren.push(new Child1().deserialize(child))
        }
        this.children = deserializedChildren;
        return this;
    }
}

class Child1{
    t: string;
    y: number;

    deserialize(input) {
        Object.assign(this, input);
        return this;
    }
}
```