# How do I cast a json on to a class/interface angularjs2

Tags: javascript, json, class, angular, typescript

The server returns something like this

```
{
    "_id": "5874e4e481009b3cbb0f0ea6",
    "description": "A home where the family lives",
    "administrator": "586df1e06485de5fc48b72a5",
    "name": "Johns House",
    "__v": 0,
    "rooms": [],
    "users": []
  }
```

What is the best technique to use this data? If I am to cast this into a class, how would I do it? I am using typescript and the angularjs framework.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I initialize a typescript object with a JSON object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22885995/how-do-i-initialize-a-typescript-object-with-a-json-object)