# Typescript casting json to object in angular using `as` doesn't work

Tags: json, angular, typescript, ionic2

Angular [tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html) has the following line in the HTTP section:

```
response => response.json().data as Hero
```

when getting hero. `response.json().data` returns the following:
[image]

I tried to do the same thing. I used Django on server side and return json using [rest_framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/). 
In Angular i have my class:

```
export class MyClass {
  name: string;
}
```

`response.json()` returned from server looks the following way:
[image]

so what i try to do is:

```
myObject: MyClass;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getResponseFromServer().then(myObject => this.myObject = myObject);
}

getResponseFromServer(): Promise<MyClass> {
    return this.http.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/myurl/")
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json() as MyClass)
      .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

and my template contains:

```
<ion-card> 
    <ion-card-header> Card Header </ion-card-header> 
    <ion-card-content>
        Response from server {{myObject.name}}
    </ion-card-content> 
</ion-card>
```

and i get Error: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined.

When i change in html `{{myObject.name}}` to `{{myObject}}`, then there's no error and Response from server and i have *Response from server [object Object]* printed.

So the question is what is the difference between my code and angular tutorial? I've seen lots of answered question like [How do I initialize a typescript object with a JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22885995/how-do-i-initialize-a-typescript-object-with-a-json-object), but i want it to be much easier with just using `as` keyword.

Comment: Please, read tag descriptions and don't use angularjs tag for Angular 2+ questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with TypeScript.

> Error: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined.

is runtime error.

The example from the guide uses directives as safeguards:

```
<div *ngIf="hero">
  <h2>{{hero.name}} details!</h2>
  ...
</div>
```

and

```
  <a *ngFor="let hero of heroes" ...>
    <div class="module hero">
      <h4>{{hero.name}}</h4>
    </div>
  </a>
```

While the code above doesn't.

When `myObject` is originally `undefined`, nothing prevents compiler from parsing `{{myObject.name}}` expression, hence the error. [Safe navigator operator](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator) (known as Elvis operator) should be used to avoid this:

`{{myObject?.name}}`