# localstorage initially returns assigned type, then type Object

Tags: arrays, typescript, types, local-storage, cart

I am developing a shopping cart which enables users to add items of type "Product" to basket. When an item is initially added it is of type "Product", however when another item(second item) is added to the Array() array, it is of type "Object" from then on. This may not make a lot of difference during manipulation, however i'd rather keep the types consistent. Someone please point out where im going wrong, much appreciated.

```
     constructor(private _http: Http) {
            localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(new Array<Product>()));
     }    


      GetCartProducts() {
           let storage:string = localStorage.getItem("cart");
           return <Array<Product>>((storage) ? JSON.parse(storage) : new Array<Product>());
      }

      AddProduct(product: Product) {
            let items =  <Array<Product>>this.GetCartProducts();

            console.log(items);
            items.push(<Product>product);
            console.log(items);
            localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(<Array<Product>>items));

      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem hides in your usage of `JSON.parse`. This method return plain javascript object without any type information attached. Therefore if you want to have your objects `typed` you must manually restore type information.

For more information have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22885995/how-do-i-initialize-a-typescript-object-with-a-json-object)

And specifically implementation in typescript [here](https://github.com/magnetnation/mgCore/blob/master/lib/Serialization.ts)