# How can i make a incomming object in typescript to a class?

Tags: class, typescript

i have a function that talks to a server. And one of these getting parametes is called "userstate". This userstate is an object. I get from this object this:

```
userstate = {
    'username' = '',
    'display-name' = ''
};
```

How can I make a class of this? I have at the moment this:

```
extends class Userstate {
    username: string;
    displayName: string;

    constructior() {
        this.username = this['username'];
        this.displayName = this['display-name'];
    }
}
```

And in my function I do this:

```
let get_user_stuff = (userstate: Userstate) => {
    console.log(userstate.username);
    console.log(userstate.displayName);
};
```

And my console says this:

```
darky_chan
undefined
```

I hope you can help me :)
Thanks in advance

Comment: not extends i wanted to write export

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I initialize a typescript object with a JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22885995/how-do-i-initialize-a-typescript-object-with-a-json-object)

Comment: sry i didn't made a duplucate

Comment: Because i have a problem with that "-" in that object and i don't know how i make a object with that - to a class :/

Comment: Ok - my bad - I see what your point is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
class Userstate {
    username: string;
    displayName: string;

    constructor(jsonObject: any) { // Notice the json object passed to constructor
        this.username = jsonObject.username;
        this.displayName = jsonObject['display-name'];
    }
}

let convertToInstance = (jsonObj: any) => (new Userstate(jsonObj));

let instance = convertToInstance({
    'username': 'name',
    'display-name': 'd-name'
});

console.log(instance);
console.log(instance.displayName);
```

Comment: The problem is this: that i get a object with a -. I can't make of this class an object. I want to use this like, when I write it should show me what features it has.

Comment: For example: userstate. and now i get a list what it has. I don't want to make all the time this: userstate['display-name'], because i think this is looking bad

Comment: @Darky_Chan But you cannot access members with `-` without the `[member-name]` notation. So you cannot to `userstate.display-name` if that is what you want. I understand your JSON data has the hyphen but if you convert it to `Userstate` instance like I showed, you can access the instance using: `instance.displayName`

Comment: mmh okay, but from where is this convertToInstance()? Sry maybe i just don't get it xD

Comment: Accidentally deleted the function when editing. It is added again.

Answer (score 0):

According to typescript [specs](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#222-property-names) you can have a property name containing invalid identifiers:

```
class Userstate
{
    username: string;
    "display-name": string;
}
```

The only problem is that you will have to access them using indexer:

```
const u = new Userstate();
u["display-name"] = 23;
```