# How to instantiate TypeScript domain objects from JSON that is returned from the server in an Angular application

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am having trouble with what I have to believe is a  fairly common situation in Angular / Typescript / JavaScript in general.  I have a simple class with some fields and some methods.

```
class Rectangle {
  width: number;
  height: number;

  area(): number {
    return this.width * this.height;
  }
}
```

I then have a service with the following method that retrieves these things from my server:

```
class RectangleService {

...  // blah blah blah

  getRectangle (id: number): Observable<Rectangle> {
    // no error handling needed - nothing ever goes wrong with web services...  :) 
    return this.http.get<Rectangle> ('http://myserver.com:8080/rectangle/' + id);  
  }
}
```

And of course, my web service returns something like

```
{width: 10, height:15}
```

But then once I get the thing back, I can't call area() on it because (I am guessing) we have a bare JavaScript associative array masquerading as a Rectangle.  Which makes sense to some degree I suppose - this isn't Java where object creation is locked down by constructors.  But what is the accepted way to get that data from JSON returned by the web service into a proper Rectangle that has the methods available?

Do I have to manually build a constructor to do this?  This obviously wouldn't be tedious in this case, but in the case where there are several nested objects, it seems like it could get out of hand quickly.

I have seen some "roll-your-own" solutions (and some are very good), but this would seem to be a very common scenario in Angular, so I find it strange that there is no commonly accepted practice or library to do this.  Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I initialize a TypeScript object with a JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22885995/how-do-i-initialize-a-typescript-object-with-a-json-object)

Comment: I think you just need to `.map()` the response from your `.get()` into `Rectangle`s

Comment: @mhodges No, that' won't add a `.area` call.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović If you create instances of the `Rectangle` class, yes it will..? OP will need a constructor function to instantiate height/width, but other than that it should work

Comment: @mhodges, Yes, I could create a constructor to do this, but for more complicated objects, you would have to ensure each class in the object graph had a suitable constructor to make this work.  For example, if I had an Employee, that had an Address, that had a Country, and country had a method, then I would have to call all of those constructors.

Comment: @mattforsythe Well, you can't have your cake and eat it, too. The entire purpose of a constructor is to do all of the setup required to *construct* instances of a class. You can't have it do that work while also not implementing it. Each respective class would have its own constructor, and all you would have to do in your Rectangle constructor is `this.address = new Address(data.address);`, `this.country = new Country(data.country);`, etc.

Comment: @mattforsythe That being said, though, I don't see why Address or Country would need to be classes - in this case, I think an `interface` would suffice. But if you actually do need to instantiate child objects, that's the way to do it

Comment: @mhodges, I totally agree with your comment about the purpose of the constructor.  One of the reasons I don't want to use a constructor solution is because the real problem we are trying to solve is deserialization.

Comment: @mattforsythe Yeah, I can kind of agree with that. There are many deserialization techniques, but as you alluded to, they only go one layer deep. Although, I'm not sure how common it is to have data that truly requires nested classes. I, personally, have never ran into that case, but I can see it's a legitimate possibility

Comment: Also confusing is the Angular tutorial's explanation of `HttpClient.get()`. The page at https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#httpclientget-returns-response-data states that 'Applying the optional type specifier, <Hero[]> , gives you a typed result object.'  This seems to be a stretch at best.

Comment: @mattforsythe For the record, your type safety with AJAX data is only as good as the developers on both ends. When you strongly type your return data, you are telling the TypeScript compiler to trust you that the data coming back is in that form - the TS compiler cannot know otherwise, so it trusts you. If the data changes, or is not *really* what you say it is, it leads to things like this.

Comment: @mattforsythe I agree the verbiage they use can be pretty confusing to those coming from a truly classical background. I guess I just have known that it won't deserialize things for me and that objects are not truly instances of a class until explicitly constructed. I probably take that knowledge for granted, because looking through the link you posted, it doesn't really mention that at all. In my opinion, they should have used a `Hero` **interface** since `Hero` only contains properties - not methods. In that case, the two are synonymous (in terms of type-safety).

Answer (score 2):

The server just returns data **formed** with properties from the defined object. It doesn't actually create an instance of the object.

Try something like this:

```
return this.http.get<Rectangle> ('http://myserver.com:8080/rectangle/' + id)
               .map(res => Object.assign(new Rectangle(), res));
```

This should create the object and then copy any of the retrieved properties into it.

Here is some sample code I used on the TypeScript playground (https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/):

```
class Hospital {
    hospital: string;
    doctors: Doctors[];
}
class Doctors {
    id: number;
    ward: string;
}

class Test {
    hospitals: Hospital[] = [];
    hospitals2: Hospital[];
    constructor() {
        this.hospitals[7] = {
            hospital: "New York Hospital",
            doctors: [{
                id: 1269,
                ward: "test"
            }]
        };
        this.hospitals2 = Object.assign(new Hospital(), this.hospitals);
    }

    data() {
        return JSON.stringify(this.hospitals) + '<br>' +
               JSON.stringify(this.hospitals2);
    }
}

let tester = new Test();

let button = document.createElement('button');
button.textContent = "Say Hello";
button.onclick = function() {
    alert(tester.data());
}

document.body.appendChild(button);
```

Comment: this will indeed work for this example, but my understanding is that it will not work if the the class (rectangle in this case) has properties that are also Objects.  In that case, those nested Objects will just be bare JavaScript objects, correct?

Comment: The Object.assign is documented here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign along with the discussion of "deep cloning".

Comment: Right, so this solution will only work in the very basic cases.  (Thanks for the link.)

Comment: "those nested Objects will just be bare JavaScript objects," no, I don't think so. They are references, not properties. I just threw together a test on TypeScript playground and it populated the child objects. You just need to be careful because they are references, not copies.

Comment: But they will not have any methods on them.

Comment: @DeborahK `this.hospitals2` starts as a `Hospital[]` and then gets reassigned to an object with `Object.assign`. I'm confused?

Comment: @DeborahK Also, even when the hospitals2 structure gets fixed, `this.hospitals2.doctors[0] instanceof Doctor === false`

Comment: @DeborahK I tested a modified example and it works. The approach will not work with classes that have constructors with parameters.

Comment: @DeborahK it will also not work for compound models which really sucks.

Comment: @mhodges Yes, you are correct. To be more clear I should have defined it as `Hospital` and not `Hospital[]` or changed how I was assigning it. I just wanted a "quick and dirty" test of whether we would see the child objects in the "copy" and we do. And for Matt, yes Hospitals2 would have methods on it if the Hospital object had methods.