# When use a interface or class in Typescript

Tags: typescript, class, interface, strong-typing

I have a simple scenario of a login that requires user's input a email and password in Typescript. I need to create some type to get this strong-typed and send it to the back-end.

Should this be written as:

```
export interface UserLogin {
  email: string;
  password: string;
}
//OR
export class UserLogin {
  email: string;
  password: string;
}
```

And how to know when is the scenario to use any of these?

Comment: One major difference is that interfaces is purely a typescript construct, only used at compile-time - that is to say, interfaces add nothing to the final transpiled javascript output, they vanish completely (which is good!). Classes however exists in javascript, so every class you create in your typescript code will also exist in the javascript output. If all you want / need is type-checking at compile time, then this is bloat that makes your js files larger. So stick to interfaces if that covers your needs, never preemptively add classes, only add a class later if you need it.

Comment: Note that your example class isn't actually valid TypeScript. It's actually impossible to create a valid instance of `UserLogin`, because neither of the properties are optional, and yet the constructor doesn't set them. With `strictPropertyInitialization` (also provided by `strict`) disabled, the compiler will ignore it, but with the entire compiler enabled it will.

Comment: From semantic and OO perspective you should use a class because the purpose of interfaces is to define the data properties and communication endpoints (methods) of objects, mainly in scenarios where more implementations of the same interface are likely i.e. because of mocking or polymorphism and generalization. The UserLogin object in the question is data (i.e. a DTO - Data Transfer Object) that will never have more than one implementation, therefore data objects don't need interfaces.

Answer (score 202, accepted):

At it's most basic, a **class** is essentially an *object factory* (ie. a blueprint of what an object is supposed to look like and then implemented), whereas an **interface** is a structure used solely for *type-checking*.

While a **class** may have initialized properties and methods to help create objects, an **interface** essentially defines the properties and type an object can have.

In the scenario you described, one would use the **interface** to set the type for UserLogin.

Comment: This is the accepted answer, and what everyone says, but then why are interfaces used anywhere other than extending classes that implement them?  Why are we allowed (and indeed encouraged) to "instantiate an object from an interface", like `foo = {} as IModel` ?

Comment: @GreenAsJade confuses me as well, I see them get used interchangeably

Comment: Accepted answer right here!

Comment: This is a while ago but when would you ever use classes?

Answer (score 53):

If you just need to declare a custom type then use interfaces. IMO, there is a very pragmatic reason - they don't get transpiled into JavaScript so the generated code is shorter.

Interfaces won't work if you need to instantiate objects with constructors or use a framework that instantiates and inject them. Then use classes or abstract classes.

Answer (score 13):

> send it to the back-end

Sending classes over the wire requires extra effort - if you use JSON content type, your class will come as plain object to your back-end code. See [numerous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22885995/how-do-i-initialize-a-typescript-object-with-a-json-object) for this question telling how to convert JSON back to a class object so it's possible to call its methods.

But since the class in your question has no methods, it does not matter, unless the back-end code will perform runtime checks using `instanceof`.

To avoid these problems, use interface which has only data members for representing objects for communicating with back-end.

Answer (score 13):

Actually both will do the job. I would suggest you to use interfaces though if you just do type-checking as it is specifically designed for that purpose.

> Classes and interfaces are powerful structures that facilitate not just object-oriented programming but also type-checking in TypeScript. A class is a blueprint from which we can create objects that share the same configuration - properties and methods. An interface is a group of related properties and methods that describe an object, but neither provides implementation nor initialisation for them.

From: https://toddmotto.com/classes-vs-interfaces-in-typescript