# Filtering with value inside an array of class objects

Tags: angular, typescript, filter

I'm trying to filter an array of class objects which have again class objects nested in it. I know it is confusing, I'll provide a sample code:

```
//class
export class Class1{
  id:number;
  team: Teams // here  another class contains 'id' and 'name'
}
// Assume that the variable this.tmpObj contains array of Class1 objects
tmpObj:Class1[];
```

So here I want to take only the Class1 objects not having team.id 100.

```
 this.tmpObj= this.tmpObj.filter(({ team }) => {
    return team.id != 100
  })
```

But this code shows error that team.id is null.I tried some other ways of filtering. But same error.
Any idea what was the error. Thanks in advance.

Console:
[image: console.log]

Comment: this.tmpObj= this.tmpObj.filter((team) => team.id !== 100) ?

Comment: you should `console.log` your `tmpObj` to see if it contains what you expect it to contain.

Comment: @MichaelDesigaud not filtering objects with team.id =100.

Comment: As I stated before, I suspect your object does not look like you expect it to look. Please show a `console.log` of your `this.tmpObj` before looping on it.

Comment: @Random its not printing because of error occured in above line

Comment: Yes, that's why I ask a console.log BEFORE your loop.

Comment: @Random it is perfect. I printed it in console. All looks good

Comment: @Random output is like:  0:  id: value team: value and so on

Comment: Please show the result in your question

Comment: @Random Sorry, I can't show that. It contains some sensitive information

Comment: @Sahal Then remove the sensitive information from it, or post a true [mcve] with non-sensitive example data so that others can demonstrate it.

Comment: You must be missing something, because the code you shown works: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nj1zzz?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: @Random I'm sharing the console result in question. Please check it

Comment: And what is the error ? It should tell you what happens

Comment: Sorry guys, I got the error. there is one null value in it. Didn't find that till now. Anyways thats for all your support

Comment: @Support one  more doubt, How can i skip null values showing error

Answer (score 0):

Why use a class here where none of it's features are required? [TS Interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) would be better fit here.

```js
interface Class1{
    id: number;
    team: Teams;
}

interface Teams {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

const tmpObj: Class1[] = [ ... ];
const filtered = tmpObj.filter(({team}) => team.id !== 100);
```

Working example: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=27&pln=11&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIBs4GcsEYDeAsAFDJnLAAmAXMiAK4C2ARtANwnnKRyO0AqEXlg7EAviRKhIsRCkHDkRUuSq0GLdp3IheEWljBRQAc1ETiJBAHsQh7owAOAeWYArWhmx4A2gF1kAF5kH20yfAoaZFwAGm4hPiVI2li6PVoAclsIDOQxPJiwpLVkACY4nkSIktwABlq43UZ9ZAywAHdrXPyxQpVw5OQAZgqE2mqogFYRtObMsAALKAgcvIKiidoAFlHeccG6htmWjJhreihu9f7iqd2qwa2ATkb01phgADdVnpI-USstnsH3QMgglCCDhc7gAdCCZAAKBH4SpiACUQQAfPFeDCqMgAISBYKHNEA4g2OzWdAQGHoawmBHw6DgslAA)

#### Update: TS Class

If you insist on using TS Class instead of interfaces, you could leverage TS [parameter properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#parameter-properties) to define and assign member variables in the constructor.

```js
class Class2 {
    constructor(
        private id: number,
        private team: TeamClass
    ) { }
}

class TeamClass {
    constructor(
        private id: number,
        private name: string
    ) { }
}

const tmpObj2: Class1[] = [ ... ];

const filtered2 = tmpObj.filter(({team}) => team.id !== 100);
console.log(filtered2);
```

Working example: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIBs4GcsEYDeAsAFDJnLAAmAXMiAK4C2ARtANwnnKRyO0AqEXlg7EAviRKhIsRCkHDkRUuSq0GLdp3IheEWljBRQAc1ETiJBAHsQh7owAOAeWYArWhmx4A2gF1kAF5kH20yfAoaZFwAGm4hPiVI2li6PVoAclsIDOQxPJiwpLVkACY4nkSIktwABlq43UZ9ZAywAHdrXPyxQpVw5OQAZgqE2mqogFYRtObMsAALKAgcvIKiidoAFlHeccG6htmWjJhreihu9f7iqd2qwa2ATkb01phgADdVnpI-USstnsH3QMgglCCDhc7gAdCCZAAKBH4SpiACUQQAfPFeDCqMgAISBYKHNGiAD05OQNjs1nQEBh6GsJgR8Og4LJkmICEwODQvKwpSURRphig9AQYGsUARRS4jmMnzgkEGGlYUD6XHliuVKEqAgSXhwRQxEQsFisAuQCkYRqwwpuoqMEqlMrl5AVX11qqY6s1WrInqVKqaLTFphNSXNXKdUNcblKngFuH8kNCN020Xu%20xqrzmrWyV16G0G5RxDxq9TzJw6XTWxYzgxm%20tutGm1fmSxWRf9AxKO3LOaihw773Ol3rvdbyEm2enz1Hpy%20PzyfwB3KBYGQbOWlCFwTATnjcOAoOgSJRCXRWPLeIhRJJ9U5lg3tPpjOZrNPYL3z6AA)

Comment: whats the difference b/w both class and interface?

Comment: @Sahal: This has already been documented extensively. You could start here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51716808/6513921

Comment: I need to instantiate object. So I should go for class only. And i tried your above code. Same error I'm getting

Comment: What is the difference with the code which is already in the question ?

Comment: @Sahal: If you insist on using TS class, use parameter properties to define and assign the member variables. If not it should be done manually. Both the methods work in the playground, if you still get an error create a minimal working example.

Comment: @Random: The variable doesn't seem to initialized in the question. Interfaces doesn't bother with it.

Comment: Actually springboot returns the values and it is stored in that variable.

Comment: @Sahal: Then you need to show how the values are retrieved, if the values indeed are of the same structure that you've shown and how is the type assigned to the response.