# How to create an interface to make type of http response in angular?

Tags: angular, interface

The json response I get from an API is in this format:

```
{
    "bill_id": 110,
    "billdate": "2021-06-23",
    "amount": 5500,
     "vendors": {
        "vendor_id": 7,
        "vendor_name": "ABC pvt ltd",
    }
}
```

So I am creating an interface to map with response.

```
export interface BillModel{
    bill_id:number,
    billdate:string,
    amount: number,
    vendors:object
}
```

**I don't know how to make the vendors field and object with an interface too. [vendor_id and vendor_name]**

That way I can map the http response properly

```
 return this.http.get<BillModel[]>(this.getbillurl);
```

I know it is very basic but I am in learning the phase. Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
export interface Vendor {
    vendor_id: number,
    vendor_name: string
}

export interface BillModel{
    bill_id:number,
    billdate:string,
    amount: number,
    vendors: Vendor
}
```

Although by the name it sounds like you might want `vendors: Vendor[]` and be expecting an  array?

Comment: Thanks Now I understood

Comment: it is not possible with class? why do you choose interface?

Comment: @KumaresanPerumal You can do it with a class if you like. I use interfaces for http responses because they don't actually end up in your compiled code, and I'm not usually doing type checking at runtime for http responses. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51716808/when-use-a-interface-or-class-in-typescript