# Angular 9 how to map 1 object to another

Tags: angular

I have an angular service that returns from the backend an Observable defined as:

```
GetAllMyResponses(): Observable<ResponsesGridResult> { ..... }
```

and the model is declared in the following way:

```
export class GridResult {
   a: string;
   b: Date;
   c: string;
   d: string;
}

export class ResponsesGridResult {
   public rowCount: number;
   public summaries: GridResult[];
}
```

So now when I go to use my method from my component I do:

```
private getResponsesSubscription : Subscription;
....
.....

this.getResponsesSubscription = this.myservice.GetAllMyResponses()
  .pipe(delay(500))
  .subscribe((result) => {
   this.selected = result.summaries;
});
```

The issue I have is that

> this.selected

declared as selected: responseSummary[] = [];

is a different type declared in the form:

```
 export class responseSummary {
       a: string;
       b: Date;
       c: string;
       d: string;
       e: string;
       f: string;
    }
 export class ResponsesSummaryGridResult {
       public rowCount: number;
       public summaries: responseSummary [];
    }
```

the responseSummary object holds all property names that are in GridResult plus extra.

So I cant do this.selected = result.summaries, because the returning object isn't the same as the object I'm trying to set. is there a way to Map one object onto the other? I cannot declare selected as the same type, because it's used in other parts of the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility would be to map your array like so :

```js
this.getResponsesSubscription = this.myservice.GetAllMyResponses()
  .pipe(delay(500))
  .subscribe((result) => {
   this.selected = result.summaries.map( summary => 
    ({...summary, e: 'value', f: 'value'}) as responseSummary
   )
  });
```

If `e` and `f` can be `undefined` then mark them as such :

```js
export class responseSummary {
   a: string;
   b: Date;
   c: string;
   d: string;
   e?: string;
   f?: string;
}
```

This will simplify the code shown above to :

```js
this.selected = result.summaries as responseSummary;
```

By the way, in your example, you define `GridResult`, `responseSummary` and `ResponsesSummaryGridResult` as classes. [Do you need to do so?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51716808/when-use-a-interface-or-class-in-typescript)