# How could I serialize/deserialize complex objects in Typescript such as the deserialized object is of the same type as the object that was serialized

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, stringify, jsonparser

I have a complex object that I want to serialize and deserialize and obtain an object of the same type.

```
let workflow = new Workflow();
console.log(`workflow is instanceof Workflow: ${workflow instanceof Workflow}`);
console.log(workflow);

let json = JSON.stringify(workflow);
console.log(json);

let workflow2 = JSON.parse(json) as Workflow;
console.log(workflow2);
console.log(`workflow2 is instanceof Workflow: ${workflow2 instanceof Workflow}`);

let workflow3: Workflow = JSON.parse(json) as Workflow;
console.log(workflow3);
console.log(`workflow3 is instanceof Workflow: ${workflow3 instanceof Workflow}`);
```

The console output is:

[image]

Is there an out of the box solution for this or I need to manually reinstantiate the complex object and set all of its properties?

Comment: `Object.assign(new Workflow, workflow3)` and yes, thats one of the reasons why I'm not using classes in JS (for things that have to be stored somewhere).

Comment: This works, i tried it, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an object's `fromJSON()` together with a `reviver` function to `JSON.parse()` to achieve what you want.

For example:

```js
type Serialized<T> = Pick<T, keyof T> & { _type: string };

class Workflow {
  foo: number;

  constructor(foo: number) {
    this.foo = foo;
  }

  public toJSON(): Serialized<Workflow> {
    return {
      _type: this.constructor.name,
      ...this
    };
  }

  public static fromJSON(source: Serialized<Workflow>): Workflow {
    return new Workflow(source.foo);
  }
}

function reviver(key: string, value: any): any {
  if (typeof value === "object" && value && "_type" in value) {
    switch (value._type) {
      case "Workflow": return Workflow.fromJSON(value);
    }
  }
  return value;
}

const w = new Workflow(42);
console.log(w instanceof Workflow);

const s = JSON.stringify(w);
console.log(s);

const w2 = JSON.parse(s, reviver) as Workflow;
console.log(w2.foo);
console.log(w2 instanceof Workflow);
```

prints:

```
true
{"_type":"Workflow","foo":42}
42
true
```

Try it out yourself at the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-xj08T89Qeu3Unizgt8x4oA)!

Comment: This answer is good, I am going to mark it as accepted. However before I received this answer I implemented Option 4 from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22886730/4233941.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an out of the box solution for this...

I've made an npm module named [esserializer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esserializer) to solve this problem: save JavaScript/TypeScript class instance during serialization, in plain JSON format, together with its class name information:

```
const ESSerializer = require('esserializer');

class Workflow {
  foo:number;
  constructor(foo:number) {
    this.foo = foo;
  }
}

const w = new Workflow(42);
console.log(w instanceof Workflow);

const s = ESSerializer.serialize(w);
console.log(s);
```

Later on, during the deserialization stage (possibly on another machine), esserializer can recursively deserialize object instance, with all Class/Property/Method information retained, using the same class definition:

```
const o = ESSerializer.deserialize(s, [Workflow]);
console.log(o.foo); // 42
console.log(o instanceof Workflow); // true
```