# TypeScript Parsing simple object to class

Tags: typescript, object

I have question about objects. I would like save values from form to precise class object.

For example. I have class TAX

```
export class TAX
{
    public name: string;
    public description?: string;
    public value: number;
    public enabled: boolean = true;
}
```

The data that I received from form:

```
{name: "2000", value: "5", enabled: true, description: "adfdasfdasfasd"}
```

Now I would like to create new variable of type TAX with data from "simple" object.
Is there any build-in function/method or something like that?

I have this solution only:

```
let entity: TAX = Object.assign(new TAX(), this.form.value);
```

Is it the best way?

Comment: Your method "works", provided there's no funny business going on with the class, but isn't type-safe.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22885995/how-do-i-initialize-a-typescript-object-with-a-json-object/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to convince the compiler to treat your form as an instance of that class.

```js
const entity = this.form.value as TAX;
```

> Sometimes you’ll end up in a situation where you’ll know more about a value than TypeScript does. Usually this will happen when you know the type of some entity could be more specific than its current type.
>
> Type assertions are a way to tell the compiler “trust me, I know what I’m doing.” A type assertion is like a type cast in other languages, but performs no special checking or restructuring of data. It has no runtime impact, and is used purely by the compiler. TypeScript assumes that you, the programmer, have performed any special checks that you need.

I do this frequently in my Angular projects. Typically I'll have a service method that may accept a certain type (usually a model) as an input. I structure my form to match the shape of the input type and then use type assertion on the form value.

Make sure you validate your form before doing this.

Comment: In this case you wouldn't know better than the compiler, you'd straight out lie to it and should yourself in the foot in the process. `instanceof` would fail to work, yiu can't use any class methods, ...

Comment: Yes -- Great points about `instanceof` and class methods. It's not *really* an instance of that class. These may be harmless concerns if you're simply doing this with an anemic model class to shuttle some fields around.

Comment: In that case you can just use an interface, though.

Comment: Yeah, I no argument here. Interface would be best.

Answer (score 1):

If you're declaring a `class` without the intent to use `instanceof` or member methods, what you most likely want is just an `interface`, which would also happen to simplify your logic. The only downside with an interface is that you can't use field initializers like `enabled: boolean = true;`

```
export interface Tax {
    name: string;
    description?: string;
    value: number;
    enabled?: boolean;
}

...

const entity: Tax = this.form.value/* as Tax */;
```

In TypeScript, this is the more conventional solution to your problem, since the only purpose of your awkward `Object.assign(new Tax(), ...)` was to satisfy the type-check of your `class` declaration when you really just needed an `interface` instead.

---

If in fact you do need to use `instanceof` or member methods, I would instead suggest adding an analogous `interface`, and create a `constructor` for your class:

```
export interface ITax {
    name: string;
    description?: string;
    value: number;
    enabled?: boolean;
}

export class Tax implements ITax {
    name: string;
    description: string | undefined;
    value: number;
    enabled: boolean;

    constructor ({ name, description, value, enabled = true }: ITax) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.value = value;
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }
};

...

const entity: Tax = new Tax(this.form.value/* as ITax */);
```

This way, you're not lying about the type of `this.form.value` *or* `entity`.

Some would argue that it's bad practice to have interfaces with `I` prefixes in TypeScript, but in this particular case I would argue it makes sense to have because your `this.form.value` is a plain object that implements the interface, while `Tax` denotes a proper instance of the respective class, which allows language constructs like `instanceof` checks, access to member methods, etc., that are not part of the base interface `ITax`.