# TS2739 Type 'any[]' is missing the following properties from type 'JSON': parse, stringify, [Symbol.toStringTag]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

In my react-typescript project I am running into a typing error when I try to pass a `JSON` as a prop.

```
class MainNewsFeed extends React.Component {
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        const bitcoinJson = [...require("./feeds/newsJson.json")];
        return (
            <NewsFeedCol json={newsJson}/>
        );
    }
}

class NewsFeedCol extends React.Component<{ newsJson:JSON },  {}> {
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        let JsonData = [...props.json]
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Row>
                <Col sm={12} md={6} lg={4}>
                    <NewsFeedItem index={1}/>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        );
    }
}


/Users/simon/Code/web/thedrewreport/frontend/thedrewreport/src/MainNewsFeed.tsx
TypeScript error in /Users/simon/Code/web/thedrewreport/frontend/thedrewreport/src/MainNewsFeed.tsx(18,26):
Type 'any[]' is missing the following properties from type 'JSON': parse, stringify, [Symbol.toStringTag]  TS2739

    17 |         return (
  > 18 |             <NewsFeedCol json={bitcoinJson}/>
       |                          ^
    19 |         );
    20 |     }
    21 | }
```

How do you properly handle typing here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I initialize a TypeScript Object with a JSON-Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22885995/how-do-i-initialize-a-typescript-object-with-a-json-object)

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you want to annotate the `newsJson` to be of type object. However, `JSON` is a module (which has JSON.parse and JSON.stringify), **not a type**. To annotate `newsJson` attribute, you will need to know the exact shape of the object that you want, probably make it into an `interface`. For example

```
interface NewsFeedsColProp {
  newsJson: {
     name: string;
     provider: string;
     id: number;
   }
}

class NewsFeedCol extends React.Component<NewsFeedsColProp ,  {}>
```

Note the fields `name`, `provider`, and `id` - I am expecting the `newsJson` to be an object with these 3 fields.

The `name`, `provider`, and `id` fields are just made-up things of mine; you need to determine the exact shape of the data that your `newsJson` prop is going to get.

If you can't know the exact shape, you can type `newsJson` as `any` type, or "unknown-object" type: `{[key: string]: any}` - which is not really a good practice

```
interface NewsFeedsColProp {
  newsJson: {
    [key: string]: any,
  }
}

// Or
interface NewsFeedsColProp {
  newsJson: any
}

class NewsFeedCol extends React.Component<NewsFeedsColProp ,  {}>
```

Hope I am making sense